# Relative paths in Python

Tags: python, relative-path, path

I'm building a simple helper script for work that will copy a couple of template files in our code base to the current directory. I don't, however, have the absolute path to the directory where the templates are stored. I do have a relative path from the script but when I call the script it treats that as a path relative to the current working directory. Is there a way to specify that this relative url is from the location of the script instead?

Comment: Similar questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165749/open-file-in-a-relative-location-in-python
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561691/python-syntaxerror-eol-while-scanning-string-literal

Comment: See also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory)

Comment: The (only) answer below using pathlib (instead of os) [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36906785/6069586)

Comment: @JWCS Did you mean [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51149057/1707427)?

Comment: @Raj the last one isn't similar at all.

Answer (score 546, accepted):

In the file that has the script, you want to do something like this:

```
import os
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(dirname, 'relative/path/to/file/you/want')
```

This will give you the absolute path to the file you're looking for.  Note that if you're using setuptools, you should probably use its [package resources API](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs#accessing-package-resources) instead.

**UPDATE**:  I'm responding to a comment here so I can paste a code sample.  :-)

> Am I correct in thinking that `__file__` is not always available (e.g. when you run the file directly rather than importing it)?

I'm assuming you mean the `__main__` script when you mention running the file directly.  If so, that doesn't appear to be the case on my system (python 2.5.1 on OS X 10.5.7):

```
#foo.py
import os
print os.getcwd()
print __file__

#in the interactive interpreter
>>> import foo
/Users/jason
foo.py

#and finally, at the shell:
~ % python foo.py
/Users/jason
foo.py
```

However, I do know that there are some quirks with `__file__` on C extensions.  For example, I can do this on my Mac:

```
>>> import collections #note that collections is a C extension in Python 2.5
>>> collections.__file__
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/lib-
dynload/collections.so'
```

However, this raises an exception on my Windows machine.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that __file__ is not always available (e.g. when you run the file directly rather than importing it)?

Comment: @Stephen Edmonds I'm using it a file that I run, rather than import, and it works great.

Comment: Note you should use os.path.join everywhere for portability: `filename = os.path.join(dir, 'relative', 'path', 'to', 'file', 'you' , 'want')`

Comment: `os.path.dirname(__file__)` can give an empty string, use `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` instead

Comment: It's a minor thing, but PLEASE don't use dir as a variable name since it is a builtin.

Comment: `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(cur_path, os.pardir))`

Comment: This is a good solution, but it won't work unless you take Dimitry Troflimov's comment, please updated your answer to reflect that.   os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)). This is an issue I had in both Ubuntu 20.0.4 and MacOS

Comment: @DmitryTrofimov If we omit the os.path.abspath, we still get a valid *relative* path from the working directory, correct?

Comment: What is `file` in `__file__` .

Comment: @Julien The special variable `__file__` contains the path (directory + file name) of the currently running script.  Note that `__file__` can fail and should be replaced by `inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())` (after `import inspect`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/6098238/1386750

Comment: Indeedn it fails for me

Answer (score 116):

It's 2018 now, and Python has already evolved to the `__future__` long time ago. So how about using the amazing [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) coming with Python 3.4 to accomplish the task instead of struggling with `os`, `os.path`, `glob` , `shutil`, etc.

So we have 3 paths here (possibly duplicated):

- `mod_path`: which is the path of the *simple helper script*
- `src_path`: which contains *a couple of template files* waiting to be copied.
- `cwd`: *current directory*, the destination of those template files.

and the problem is: **we don't have** the full path of `src_path`, only know **its relative path** to the `mod_path`.

Now let's solve this with the amazing [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
# Hope you don't be imprisoned by legacy Python code :)
from pathlib import Path

# `cwd`: current directory is straightforward
cwd = Path.cwd()

# `mod_path`: According to the accepted answer and combine with future power
# if we are in the `helper_script.py`
mod_path = Path(__file__).parent
# OR if we are `import helper_script`
mod_path = Path(helper_script.__file__).parent

# `src_path`: with the future power, it's just so straightforward
relative_path_1 = 'same/parent/with/helper/script/'
relative_path_2 = '../../or/any/level/up/'
src_path_1 = (mod_path / relative_path_1).resolve()
src_path_2 = (mod_path / relative_path_2).resolve()
```

In the future, it's just that simple.

---

Moreover, we can select and check and copy/move those template files with [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
if src_path != cwd:
    # When we have different types of files in the `src_path`
    for template_path in src_path.glob('*.ini'):
        fname = template_path.name
        target = cwd / fname
        if not target.exists():
            # This is the COPY action
            with target.open(mode='wb') as fd:
                fd.write(template_path.read_bytes())
            # If we want MOVE action, we could use:
            # template_path.replace(target)
```

Comment: In summary: `from pathlib import Path` `script_dir=Path(__file__).parent` `template_path=(script_dir / template_name).resolve()`

Comment: @4myle: resolve the `__file__` path _first_, for scripts it is possibly the relative path given to the interpreter. So `script_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent`. From there on out `script_dir` is absolute, and everything else can be built on top of that. Further `resolve()` calls are only needed if you need to resolve symlinks.

Comment: Then again, since the __past__, `__file__` can fail and should not be used.  Instead, use `~inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())` (after `import inspect`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/6098238/1386750

Answer (score 76):

you need `os.path.realpath` (sample below adds the parent directory to your path)

```
import sys,os
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath('..'))
```

Comment: `os.path.dirname(__file__)` gave me an empty string. This worked perfectly.

Comment: This seems to give the parent of the directory the script is run from, not of the script's location.

Comment: `os.path.realpath('..')` gives you the parent directory of the **current working dir**. That's usually **not** what you want.

Comment: @DarraghEnright: That only happens in a Python-script-to-exe packaging environment. That's one of the rare exceptions where relying on the current working dir would be the alternative.

Answer (score 76):

As mentioned in the accepted answer

```
import os
dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(dir, '/relative/path/to/file/you/want')
```

I just want to add that

> the latter string can't begin with the backslash , infact no string
>   should include a backslash

It should be something like

```
import os
dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(dir, 'relative','path','to','file','you','want')
```

The accepted answer can be misleading in some cases , please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945920/why-doesnt-os-path-join-work-in-this-case) link for details

Comment: Yes using `os.path.join` is better because it joins them with the OS-specific separator.

Comment: `'/relative/path...'` is not a relative path. Is that intentional?

Comment: This answer is now outdated, as the top answer has been edited to use a proper relative path in `os.path.join()`. What is left is the preference to use separate strings for each path element over hardcoding the path separator.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, the top answer has been edited to match this in part, but the separate strings is not a preference - separating the stings like this makes it os-independent.

Answer (score 16):

Consider my code:

```
import os


def readFile(filename):
    filehandle = open(filename)
    print filehandle.read()
    filehandle.close()



fileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))
print fileDir

#For accessing the file in the same folder
filename = "same.txt"
readFile(filename)

#For accessing the file in a folder contained in the current folder
filename = os.path.join(fileDir, 'Folder1.1/same.txt')
readFile(filename)

#For accessing the file in the parent folder of the current folder
filename = os.path.join(fileDir, '../same.txt')
readFile(filename)

#For accessing the file inside a sibling folder.
filename = os.path.join(fileDir, '../Folder2/same.txt')
filename = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath(filename))
print filename
readFile(filename)
```

Comment: When I run this in windows, I recieve an error:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<path>'

where <path> has the correct path segments but uses \\ for separators.

Comment: i was able to get a relative path by using 
```filename = os.path.abspath('../Folder2/same.txt')```

Answer (score 12):

See [sys.path](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path)
As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter.

Use this path as the root folder from which you [apply your relative path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

```
>>> import sys
>>> import os.path
>>> sys.path[0]
'C:\\Python25\\Lib\\idlelib'
>>> os.path.relpath(sys.path[0], "path_to_libs") # if you have python 2.6
>>> os.path.join(sys.path[0], "path_to_libs")
'C:\\Python25\\Lib\\idlelib\\path_to_libs'
```

Comment: That's not necessarily true.  Usually sys.path[0] is an empty string or a dot, which is a relative path to the current directory.  If you want the current directory, use os.getcwd.

Comment: The original poster commented that the current working directory is the wrong place to base the relative path from. You are correct in saying that sys.path[0] is not always valid.

Comment: No, `sys.path[0]` is not always set to the parent directory. Python code can be invoked with `-c` or `-m` or via an embedded interpreter, at which point `sys.path[0]` is set to something different altogether.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using

```
import os
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(dirname, 'relative/path/to/file/you/want')
```

as in the accepted answer, it would be more robust to use:

```
import inspect
import os
dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.stack()[0][1]))
filename = os.path.join(dirname, 'relative/path/to/file/you/want')
```

because using __file__ will return the file from which the module was loaded, if it was loaded from a file, so if the file with the script is called from elsewhere, the directory returned will not be correct.

These answers give more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31867043/5542253 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/50502/5542253

Comment: `inspect.stack()` is an *expensive* function to call. It retrieves info for all stack frames, which you then discard and only get the top one for. It basically calls `inspect.getfile()` on the module object, which just returns `module.__file__`. You are far better of just using `__file__`.

Answer (score 8):

From what suggest others and from [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use) documentation, a simple (but not ideal) solution is the following (suppose the file we need to refer to is `Test/data/users.csv`):

```py
# Current file location: Tests/src/long/module/subdir/some_script.py
from pathlib import Path

# back to Tests/
PROJECT_ROOT = Path(__file__).parents[4]
# then down to Test/data/users.csv
CSV_USERS_PATH = PROJECT_ROOT / 'data' / 'users.csv'  

with CSV_USERS_PATH.open() as users:
    print(users.read())
```

This works but looks a bit odd because if you move `some_script.py` around, the path to the root of our project may change (and we would therefore need to change the `parents[4]` part).

I think I found a better solution that, based on the same idea.
We will use a file `paths.py` to store where the root of the project is, this file will remain at the same location compared to the root directory.

```bash
Tests
├── data
│  └── users.csv
└── src
   ├── long
   │  └── module
   │     └── subdir
   │        └── some_script.py
   ├── main.py
   └── paths.py
```

Where `paths.py`'s only responsability is to provide `PROJECT_ROOT`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

PROJECT_ROOT = Path(__file__).parents[1]
```

All scripts can now use `paths.PROJECT_ROOT` to express absolute paths from the root of the project. For example in `src/long/module/subdir/some_script.py` we could have:

```py
from paths import PROJECT_ROOT

CSV_USERS_PATH = PROJECT_ROOT / 'data' / 'users.csv'

def hello():
    with CSV_USERS_PATH.open() as f:
        print(f.read())
```

And everything goes as expected:

```bash
~/Tests/src/$ python main.py

/Users/cglacet/Tests/data/users.csv
hello, user

~/Tests/$ python src/main.py

/Users/cglacet/Tests/data/users.csv
hello, user
```

The `main.py` script simply is:

```py
from long.module.subdir import some_script

some_script.hello()
```

Answer (score 6):

## summary of the most important commands

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join('/home/user/tmp', 'subfolder')
'/home/user/tmp/subfolder'
>>> os.path.normpath('/home/user/tmp/../test/..')
'/home/user'
>>> os.path.relpath('/home/user/tmp', '/home/user')
'tmp'
>>> os.path.isabs('/home/user/tmp')
True
>>> os.path.isabs('/tmp')
True
>>> os.path.isabs('tmp')
False
>>> os.path.isabs('./../tmp')
False
>>> os.path.realpath('/home/user/tmp/../test/..') # follows symbolic links
'/home/user'
```

A detailed description is found in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html).
These are linux paths. Windows should work analogous.

Answer (score 4):

Hi first of all you should understand functions **os.path.abspath(path)** and **os.path.relpath(path)**

In short **os.path.abspath(path)** makes a **relative path** to **absolute path**. And if the path provided is itself a absolute path then the function returns the same path.

similarly **os.path.relpath(path)** makes a **absolute path** to **relative path**. And if the path provided is itself a relative path then the function returns the same path.

***Below example can let you understand the above concept properly***:

suppose i have a file **input_file_list.txt** which contains list of input files to be processed by my python script.

D:\conc\input1.dic

D:\conc\input2.dic

D:\Copyioconc\input_file_list.txt

If you see above folder structure, **input_file_list.txt** is present in **Copyofconc** folder and the files to be processed by the python script are present in **conc** folder

But the content of the file **input_file_list.txt** is as shown below:

..\conc\input1.dic

..\conc\input2.dic

And my python script is present in **D:** drive.

And the relative path provided in the **input_file_list.txt** file are relative to the path of **input_file_list.txt** file.

So when python script shall executed the current working directory (use **os.getcwd()** to get the path)

As my relative path is relative to **input_file_list.txt**, that is **"D:\Copyofconc"**, i have to change the current working directory to **"D:\Copyofconc"**.

So i have to use **os.chdir('D:\Copyofconc')**, so the current working directory shall be **"D:\Copyofconc"**.

Now to get the files **input1.dic** and **input2.dic**, i will read the lines "..\conc\input1.dic" then shall use the command

**input1_path= os.path.abspath('..\conc\input1.dic')** (to change relative path to absolute path. Here as current working directory is "D:\Copyofconc", the file ".\conc\input1.dic" shall be accessed relative to "D:\Copyofconc")

so **input1_path** shall be "D:\conc\input1.dic"

Answer (score 4):

This code will return the absolute path to the main script.

```
import os
def whereAmI():
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__import__("__main__").__file__))
```

This will work even in a module.

Comment: Instead of re-importing, you'd use `sys.modules['__main__'].__file__`.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative which works for me:

```
this_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__) 
filename = os.path.realpath("{0}/relative/file.path".format(this_dir))
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Example

---

Here's an example, tested in Python '3.9.5`:

your current directory: `'c:\project1\code\'` 
and you want to access the following folder: `'c:\project1\dataset\train\'`. 
Then you can access the folder using the following address: `'../dataset/train/'`

#### References

---

If you want some more information about `path in Python`, read this:

- [`PEP - 355`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0355/)
- [`PEP - 519`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0519/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my sumup:

First, define the tool function named `relpath`, which convert a relative path to current file into a relative path to cwd

```
import os
relpath = lambda p: os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), p))
```

Then we use it to wrap paths which is relative to current file

```
path1 = relpath('../src/main.py')
```

And you can also call `sys.path.append()` to import file relative to current file position

```
sys.path.append(relpath('..')) # so that you can import from upper dir
```

The full example code : https://gist.github.com/luochen1990/9b1ffa30f5c4a721dab5991e040e3eb1

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is using `sys.path.insert`. Then I specified the  directory I needed to go. For example I just needed to go up one directory.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../')
```

Comment: This relies on the current working directory, which could be radically different from what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

I think to work with all systems  use "ntpath" instead of "os.path". Today, it works well with Windows, Linux and Mac OSX.

```
import ntpath
import os
dirname = ntpath.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(dirname, 'relative/path/to/file/you/want')
```

Answer (score 0):

From `C:\Users\xyz\myFolder` to `C:\Users\xyz\testdata` :

```
import os
working_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
# C:\Users\xyz\myFolder
print(working_dir)
updated_working_dir = os.path.join(os.path.realpath(working_dir + '/../'), 'testdata')
# C:\Users\xyz\testdata
print(updated_working_dir)
```

> Output

```
C:\Users\xyz\myFolder
C:\Users\xyz\testdata
```

Answer (score 0):

Say the current archive named "Helper" and the upper directory named "Workshop", and the template files are in \Workshop\Templates, then the relative path in Python is "..\Templates".

Answer (score 0):

This a simple way to add a **relative** path to the system path set . For example, for frequent case when the target directory is one level above (thus, `'/../'`) the working directory:

```
import os
import sys
workingDir = os.getcwd()
targetDir = os.path.join(os.path.relpath(workingDir + '/../'),'target_directory')
sys.path.insert(0,targetDir)
```

This solution was tested for:

> Python 3.9.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul 11 2021,
> 03:37:25) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this applies to some of the older versions, but I believe Python 3.3 has native relative path support.

For example the following code should create a text file in the same folder as the python script:

```
open("text_file_name.txt", "w+t")
```

(note that there shouldn't be a forward or backslash at the beginning if it's a relative path)

Comment: right, so this will work from the CWD which is not what the OP asks for. The want to work from the scripts location.