# Why doesn't os.path.join() work in this case?

Tags: python, path

The below code will not join, when debugged the command does not store the whole path but just the last entry.

```
os.path.join('/home/build/test/sandboxes/', todaystr, '/new_sandbox/')
```

When I test this it only stores the `/new_sandbox/` part of the code.

Answer (score 559, accepted):

The latter strings shouldn't start with a slash. If they start with a slash, then they're considered an "absolute path" and everything before them is discarded.

Quoting the [Python docs for `os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

> If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component.

Note on Windows, the behaviour in relation to drive letters, which seems to have changed compared to earlier Python versions:

> On Windows, the drive letter is not reset when an absolute path component (e.g., `r'\foo'`) is encountered. If a component contains a drive letter, all previous components are thrown away and the drive letter is reset. Note that since there is a current directory for each drive, `os.path.join("c:", "foo")` represents a path relative to the current directory on drive `C:` (`c:foo`), not `c:\foo`.

Comment: -1: **No** string should include a "/".  One whole point of os.path.join is to prevent putting any slashes in the path.

Comment: this is not cool. if i explicitly ask to join those paths (or strings) do it if there is a leading '/' or not on that path/string.

Comment: if you want that, just use str.join(), this is os.path and therefore it's consistent with its package semantics.

Comment: The problem with str.join() is, of course, that it won't eliminate double slashes.   I think this is the primary purpose for folks using os.path.join.  e.g. '/'.join(['/etc/', '/conf']) results in three slashes: '/etc///conf'

Comment: @DustinRasener You can use [``os.path.normpath``](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) to achieve that aim.

Comment: @S.Lott Are you saying the first string shouldn't start with a slash or that it shouldn't include a trailing slash?

Comment: no clue why people are frustrated over os.path.join behavior. In other languages, the equivalent path-join library/method behaves the exact same. It's safer, and makes more sense.

Comment: I think the example of os.path.sep should be added to this, or marked as the recommended option. This answer provides accurate information, but does not provide a solution.

Comment: This is frustrating because it's **implicit magic**, contrary to the [cardinal heuristic](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020) of "Explicit is better than implicit." And it _is_. Language designers may believe they know better, but there exist obvious and demonstrably safe reasons to occasionally want to do this. Now we can't. This is why we can't have good things.

Comment: @mmcrae: in which other languages is it true? it is most definitely _not_ true of golang: https://golang.org/pkg/path/#Join Expand the example and click 'run'. I also don't understand how python's way can be considered safer... user input with leading slashes could result in referencing critical system files. If leading slashes aren't treated specially, then (at worst) the path references a deep path to a file/directory that doesn't exist. Granted, user input should be sanitized... but this function should not exacerbate the problem!

Comment: @DonCheadle which language? I just tried with nodejs and I didn't see this behavior

Comment: What is a valid (preferably common) scenario where one would want a later argument in `os.path.join` to override a former path part (since a leading slash effectively removes all prior arguments).

Comment: Not allowing / after the initial absolute paths (and requiring only relative paths afterwards) is not bad, but Python should throw an exception - rather than silently changing the path. (The use case of "I might want to override the initial path I provided with a following absolute path argument ia  a bad choice for a method supposed to join paths).

Comment: @chris you've got your `pwd`, somebody (user) gives you the path of a file, that may well be a relative path to the pwd, or an absolute path. What you want is for `os.path.join( pwd, path)` to ignore the pwd if path is a relative path, and to append it otherwise. This is probably the scenario the developers had in mind

Answer (score 170):

The idea of `os.path.join()` is to make your program cross-platform (linux/windows/etc).

Even one slash ruins it.

So it only makes sense when being used with some kind of a reference point like
`os.environ['HOME']` or `os.path.dirname(__file__)`.

Comment: The prepended slash in the relative path is what was screwing it up for me... removing it fixed it.. thanks!

Comment: Upvoted for "_Even one slash ruins it._"

Answer (score 95):

`os.path.join()` can be used in conjunction with `os.path.sep` to create an absolute rather than relative path.

```
os.path.join(os.path.sep, 'home','build','test','sandboxes',todaystr,'new_sandbox')
```

Comment: The use of `os.path.sep` as a first element to build an absolute path is better than any other answer here! The whole point of using `os.path` rather than basic str methods is to avoid writing `/`. Putting every subdirectory as a new argument and removing all slashes is also great. It would probably be a good idea to make sure with a check that `todaystr` does not start with a slash! ;)

Comment: This works on windows as well (python 2.7.6). It did not intefere with 'C:\' and joined the subdirectories.

Comment: @snooze92 The only problem is that it's more verbose and much less readable.

Comment: Indeed. Trade-offs I guess ;)

Answer (score 36):

Do not use forward slashes at the beginning of path components, except when refering to the root directory:

```
os.path.join('/home/build/test/sandboxes', todaystr, 'new_sandbox')
```

see also: http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join

Answer (score 33):

To help understand why this surprising behavior isn't *entirely* terrible, consider an application which accepts a config file name as an argument:

```
config_root = "/etc/myapp.conf/"
file_name = os.path.join(config_root, sys.argv[1])
```

If the application is executed with:

```
$ myapp foo.conf
```

The config file `/etc/myapp.conf/foo.conf` will be used.

But consider what happens if the application is called with:

```
$ myapp /some/path/bar.conf
```

Then `myapp` *should* use the config file at `/some/path/bar.conf` (and not `/etc/myapp.conf/some/path/bar.conf` or similar).

It may not be great, but I believe this is the motivation for the absolute path behaviour.

Comment: Thanks! I had always hated this behavior until reading your answer! It's documented in https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.join, but not the motivation for it.

Comment: This moment when you need exactly the solution many people deem as terrible.

Comment: gotta disagree, it is entirely terrible. In this case, you should not be using a naive `sys.argv` input to determine whether to prepend the `config_root` or not. All `os.path.join` should be concerned with is joining file path elements.

Comment: the problem is that the name is badly chosen. what `os.path.join(p1, p2)` does is not really joining `p1` and `p2`, it's taking `p2` relatively to `p1` (or absolutely if `p2` is an absolute path)

Comment: So a specific use case should determine how a function behaves for all other use cases? Makes no sense.

Comment: It does make sense, and the name is fine as long as you're not assuming it will behave like `str.join`. That's how you join an absolute path, because that's exactly what it means for it to be an _absolute_ path. Perhaps it helps to think of it as where you'd end up after a chain of `cd` commands, not as a string joining operation.

Comment: thanks. makes sense. but it was unintuitive as a beginner.

Answer (score 16):

It's because your `'/new_sandbox/'` begins with a `/` and thus is assumed to be relative to the root directory. Remove the leading `/`.

Answer (score 16):

**Try combo of `split("/")` and `*` for strings with existing joins.**

```
import os

home = '/home/build/test/sandboxes/'
todaystr = '042118'
new = '/new_sandbox/'

os.path.join(*home.split("/"), todaystr, *new.split("/"))
```

**How it works...**

`split("/")` turns existing path into list: `['', 'home', 'build', 'test', 'sandboxes', '']`

`*` in front of the list breaks out each item of list its own parameter

Comment: this turns it into a relative path and not an absolute path

Comment: Perfect for working with endpoints with leading slashes. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

To make your function more portable, use it as such:

```
os.path.join(os.sep, 'home', 'build', 'test', 'sandboxes', todaystr, 'new_sandbox')
```

or

```
os.path.join(os.environ.get("HOME"), 'test', 'sandboxes', todaystr, 'new_sandbox')
```

Answer (score 5):

Try with `new_sandbox` only

```
os.path.join('/home/build/test/sandboxes/', todaystr, 'new_sandbox')
```

Answer (score 4):

do it like this, without too the extra slashes

```
root="/home"
os.path.join(root,"build","test","sandboxes",todaystr,"new_sandbox")
```

Comment: `os.sep` instead of `/` in the beggining

Answer (score 1):

```
os.path.join("a", *"/b".split(os.sep))
'a/b'
```

a fuller version:

```
import os

def join (p, f, sep = os.sep):
    f = os.path.normpath(f)
    if p == "":
        return (f);
    else:
        p = os.path.normpath(p)
        return (os.path.join(p, *f.split(os.sep)))

def test (p, f, sep = os.sep):
    print("os.path.join({}, {}) => {}".format(p, f, os.path.join(p, f)))
    print("        join({}, {}) => {}".format(p, f, join(p, f, sep)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # /a/b/c for all
    test("\\a\\b", "\\c", "\\") # optionally pass in the sep you are using locally
    test("/a/b", "/c", "/")
    test("/a/b", "c")
    test("/a/b/", "c")
    test("", "/c")
    test("", "c")
```

Comment: What if os.sep is actually `"\"`? Then your first example becomes `os.path.join("a", *"/b".split("\\"))`, which yields `"/b"`... I doubt that's the intended result.

Comment: Updated - I suppose you have to give a hint as the path sep you are using locally independent of that of the os you are running on

Comment: Yes. Alternatively one could split on both commonly used options ... but then some other OS could come up with a third.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer following code snippet for understanding `os.path.join(a, b)`

```
a = '/home/user.name/foo/'
b = '/bar/file_name.extension'

print(os.path.join(a, b))
>>> /bar/file_name.extension
```

OR

```
a = '/home/user.name/foo'
b = '/bar/file_name.extension'
print(os.path.join(a, b))
>>> /bar/file_name.extension
```

But, when

```
a = '/home/user.name/foo/'
b = 'bar/file_name.extension'

print(os.path.join(a, b))
>>> /bar/file_name.extension
```

OR

```
a = '/home/user.name/foo'
b = 'bar/file_name.extension'
print(os.path.join(a, b))
>>> /home/user.name/foo/bar/file_name.extension
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that a similar issue can bite you if you use `os.path.join()` to include an extension that already includes a dot, which is what happens automatically when you use `os.path.splitext()`. In this example:

```
components = os.path.splitext(filename)
prefix = components[0]
extension = components[1]
return os.path.join("avatars", instance.username, prefix, extension)
```

Even though `extension` might be `.jpg` you end up with a folder named "foobar" rather than a file called "foobar.jpg". To prevent this you need to append the extension separately:

```
return os.path.join("avatars", instance.username, prefix) + extension
```

Answer (score 0):

you can `strip` the `'/'`:

```
>>> os.path.join('/home/build/test/sandboxes/', todaystr, '/new_sandbox/'.strip('/'))
'/home/build/test/sandboxes/04122019/new_sandbox'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your laptop maybe running Window. And Window annoyingly use back lash instead of forward slash'/'. 
To make your program cross-platform (linux/windows/etc).
You shouldn't provide any slashes (forward or backward) in your path if you want `os.path.join` to handle them properly. you should using:

```
os.path.join(os.environ.get("HOME"), 'test', 'sandboxes', todaystr, 'new_sandbox')
```

Or throw some `Path(__file__).resolve().parent` (path to parent of current file) or anything so that you don't use any slash inside `os.path.join`

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend to strip from the second and the following strings the string `os.path.sep`, preventing them to be interpreted as absolute paths:

```
first_path_str = '/home/build/test/sandboxes/'
original_other_path_to_append_ls = [todaystr, '/new_sandbox/']
other_path_to_append_ls = [
    i_path.strip(os.path.sep) for i_path in original_other_path_to_append_ls
]
output_path = os.path.join(first_path_str, *other_path_to_append_ls)
```