# Python directory structure on Windows vs Linux

Tags: python, windows, linux, directory, compatibility

I am writing a Python script on Windows, that needs to work on a Red Hat Linux machine. On Windows,

```
os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
```

returns something like

```
C:\Users\Me\...\CurrentDirectory
```

without a trailing \ .

I'm unable to run it on Linux, but to my knowledge it would be more like

```
/home/Me/.../CurrentDirectory
```

with the slashes going the other way, and I'm uncertain about a trailing / . First of all, is there one? Secondly, how do I deal with this issue? The script doesn't have to work on both Windows and Linux, just Linux, in the end. Though I can only test it on Windows :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't matter if you use `os.path.join()`

See:

- [Python os.path.join on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422798/python-os-path-join-on-windows)
- [Why doesn't os.path.join() work in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945920/os-path-join-python)

Answer (score 2):

The behavior would be more or less the same across the OS. Instead of using \ or / use

```
 os.sep
```

inside your code. Do not try to hardcode anything