# an os.path.join() that doesn't discard before leading slash?

Tags: python, os.path

Python's `os.path.join` has been [described as "mostly pointless"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1945930/14420) because it discards any arguments prior to one containing a leading slash. Leaving aside for the moment that this is intentional and documented behaviour, is there a readily available function or code pattern which doesn't discard like this?

Given `HOMEPATH=\users\myname`, the following will discard the beginning of the path

```
print os.path.join('C:\one', os.environ.get("HOMEPATH"), 'three')
```

result:

```
\Users\myname\three
```

desired:

```
C:\one\Users\myname\three
```

Having been bitten by this a few times, I'm pretty good now at noticing a leading slash when it's something I've written, but what about when when you don't know what the incoming string is looking like, as in this example?

Comment: I'm sorry that this has bitten you a few times, but it's an *intentional* and documented feature.

Comment: The docs make it clear this is intentional behaviour, but given that the "mostly pointless" comment I borrowed from the linked answer has been upvoted 14 or more times I'm certainly not alone in thinking there should be an alternative.

Comment: The alternative, certainly, is to make sure your arguments don't start with a slash.  E.g. one line of `args = [a[1:] for a in args if a.startswith('\\') else a]` or something to that effect.  I suspect that most people understand how it's supposed to work.  Alternatively fix HOMEPATH; on Windows this is intended to be at the fs root but if you're using it in a different way then you should make it look like a relative path rather than an absolute one.

Comment: @mattwilkie: I comment cannot be *downvoted*. I would have done so if I could have. Judging by the question quality of many first-time Python question askers, it won't be hard to find 14 people that misunderstand why `os.path.join()` does this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe `os.environ.get("HOMEPATH").lstrip(os.path.sep)`... it would be trivial to write your own version of `join` that did this on every argument (or the second and subsequent).

Comment: I wasn't copying your answer ;-) Just typing it on a phone took longer.

Answer (score 6):

Just strip the slash

```
path = os.environ.get("HOMEPATH").lstrip(os.path.sep)
os.path.join('C:\one', path, 'three')
```