# opening a file in a function python 3

Tags: python-3.x, errno

I'm a beginner trying to open a file as part of a function where the file name/path is the variable in the function. I've written one but am getting an error on a similar function. Here's the function code:

```
def read_board(board_file):
    """ (file path) -> list of str

    Return a board read from open file board_file. 

    >>>read_board('C:\Python33\Doc\theboard1.txt') 
    """

    bo_file = open(board_file, 'r')
    lines = bo_file.readlines()

    return lines
```

I'm getting this error

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\Python33\Doc\theboard1.txt'

The path is correct (triple checked) and I'm using that example to test the file read.

Comment: Please post correct (syntactically) python code. as currently formatted it's not valid.

Comment: cleaned up the code and nesting, if that was your meaning

Answer (score 2):

You need to use double backslash the escape the backslash, the following will work:

```
read_board('C:\\Python33\\Doc\\theboard1.txt')
```

This is so that python treats the second `\` as a *literal* and doesn't not use it as an *escape* character for the character after it as in your case.

Comment: thanks, got it working now. not sure how the other one called anything but i'm on track.

Comment: @sharkysmachine: To be more explicit, the `\t` in your path was converted to the tabulator character. Try to print your original string where backslashes were not doubled (and when the string literal is not marked as `r'raw string literal'`).

Answer (score 2):

I'd normally suggest using `os.path.join` but since Windows paths are so brain damaged anyway, that's not going to help much.¹

One way to get it right is to use the raw Python string which doesn't interpret backslashes:

```
open(r'c:\stupid\junk.txt')
```

or just pretend that DOS was a bad dream and use forward slashes like god intended:

```
open('c:/stupid/junk.txt')
```

---

¹exercise for the reader: what does `os.path.join('c:', 'junk.dat')` return? Is it different behavior than than `os.path.join('stupid', 'junk.txt')? Has this been a [confusion for a while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945920/os-path-join-python)?

Answer (score 0):

And you Can Using ::

> os.sep

Between Files like

> ("C:"+os.sep+"user")

After importing os module