# python : join() called with 2 arguments in list comprehension?

Tags: python

I am new to python. This code is from "Dive Into Python" by Mark Pilgrim, it appears that join() is being called with 2 args, it works fine:

```
dirname="/usr/"
[f for f in os.listdir(dirname) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dirname,f))]
```

But if you try:

```
smthn="data"
smthnelse="otherdata"
print "\n".join(smthn,smthnelse)
```

We get an error that join() can take only one argument.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Are you confusing it with `str.join`?

Comment: Sorry, what's your question?

Comment: one is str.join(), the other is from os module, have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945920/os-path-join-python

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary thanks yea got confused with str.join

Answer (score 4):

`os.path.join` takes as arguments an arbitrary number of strings, `str.join` instead takes as one argument a iterable providing strings. These two functions are individual functions.

Answer (score 0):

**Look Using str.join() like this:**

```
smthn="data"
smthnelse="otherdata"

print( "\n",smthn.join(smthnelse) )
```

*Because you are put  smthnelse between the spaces in smthn >>"data"*

os.path.join() not look like str.join

the second for string and seq 
and the first only for File System paths.