# Python3 - os.path.join doesn't join the paths

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a python code that scans the `subdirectories` for files, and based on a list it has `(csv file)`, it checks if the files exist or not.

So far, I can get the absolute path, and then join it with a string, if I do:

```
    base_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    csv_path = os.path.join(my_path, csv_filename)
```

And I can successfully locate my `csv` and pass it through pandas or the `csv` reader from Python.

However, when I go through my `csv` where the filenames are (which are correct), and then try and do:

```
    base_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    full_path = os.path.join(base_dir, path, filename)
```

- Note that path is the a `subdirectory`, and filename is the actual filename I want to check.

When I output the `base_dir` and full_path, I get the following, respectively:

```
    /home/myname/projectFolder
    /subfolder/filename.extension
```

instead of having:

```
  /home/myname/projectFolder/subfolder/filename.extension
```

Something is obviously wrong with what's happening. I need the complete `filepath` to run `os.path.exists()` to see if the file is there or not, but since what I get with the full_path is just the relative path,

I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: change `/subfolder/filename.extension` to `subfolder/filename.extension`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

> [...]  If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component.

So most likely `path` starts with a slash, i.e. `path = "/subfolder"` and hence the previous `base_dir` is discarded.

Answer (score 3):

If the stings start with the `/` then it would consider it as an `absolute path` and that is not desired.

So try to remove the `slash` from the beginning of the string.

I've found another stackoverflow link which may help you:

> [Why doesn't os.path.join() work in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945920/why-doesnt-os-path-join-work-in-this-case)

For the final result you just need to try not to have the slash in your path.