# Collectstatic referencing to wrong path to folder

Tags: django, collectstatic

When executing the command 'collectstatic', python looks into the wrong folder, `Dev/staticfiles`, when my staticfiles are saved in the folder: `[..]/Dev/bidding_tool_project/project/staticfiles`

Would you have any idea how/why this happens?

Comment: Please, can you show your `STATIC_ROOT` setting (if you have specified)?

Comment: Sure: `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'project/staticfiles')`, where `PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`.

Comment: Exactly which commands did you use in the terminal and the Python console?

Comment: in my settings module, I have added the line: `print('STATIC_ROOT:', STATIC_ROOT)`

and in the python console:
- `from project import settings`
- `settings.STATIC_ROOT`

Comment: I doubt that from the console, you are improting another project's settings module. Are you sure it is not the case?

Comment: I thought this could be a reason and so I saved the settings module into a specific folder (`project`), within my larger project (`xxx_project`) but the error persisted. I don't think I am importing from an other project. I tried again just now creating a brand new project from scratch and have the same issue again: the name of the root folder is missing

Comment: Wait, so the issue is `the name of the root folder is missing`, or it is giving an incorrect value? I think in the question, you have mentioned it is giving an incorrect value.

Comment: Apologies what I meant was the path was not correct. In my initial statement / question, you will see that the path displayed is not the same in each case (STATIC_ROOT from within the settings module and settings.STATIC_ROOT as shown in the python console) where i would expect them to be exactly equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An other SO answer helped: `os.path.join` considers anything after a slash as being an absolute path. When using `os.path.join`, the path should be declared as: `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')` and not `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project/staticfiles')`

the post that helped me: [Why doesn't os.path.join() work in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945920/why-doesnt-os-path-join-work-in-this-case)