# os.path.join returns "C:/..."

Tags: python, glob

I am using the following code

```
import os
import glob


vae_checkpoints_path = r"../checkpoints/vae"
p = os.path.abspath(vae_checkpoints_path)
assert os.path.exists(p)
print(p)  # prints 'C:\\code\\EPMD\\Kodex\\Templates\\Testing\\Research\\checkpoints\\vae'
q = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(vae_checkpoints_path), r"/**/*.ckpt")
```

and q is now

> ```
> C:/**/*.ckpt
> ```

---

Why is `os.path.join` eliminating the entire start of the path and how to fix it?

Comment: what OS are you using? Windows?

Comment: @griffin_cosgrove yes

Comment: Use `r"**/*.ckpt"` instead. The leading slash is what's wrong.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Thanks. that was a long night.

Comment: Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1945930/5386938).