# os.path.join not join directory and file

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, filepath

I wrote a simple function and I believe that I done it properly, but I get something wrong.

My code:

```
array = ['/home/sergey/Документы/008.jpeg']
save_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(array[0]), "Converted_files")
os.makedirs(save_dir)

for file in array:
    if file.endswith(srcSfx):
        im = Image.open(file).convert("RGB")
        print (save_dir)
        p = os.path.join(save_dir, file[:-len(srcSfx)] + destSfx)
        print(p)
        im.save(p, destSfx)
```

I want to create a folder and to save some images in it. But the images are saved in the original folder, not in the `'save_dir'` folder.

Printout from code:

```
/home/sergey/Документы/Converted_files
/home/sergey/Документы/008.png
```

Why does `'008.png'` not placed into `'save_dir'`?

Comment: Instead of saying `array[0]`, provide the actual string please. Otherwise this is not reproducible. Or better yet, provide a sample of a couple of elements from `array`.

Comment: Take a closer look at `file[:-len(srcSfx)] + destSfx`.  From the `join` docstring: "If any component is an absolute path, all previous path components will be discarded."

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is the first and only element from array
/home/sergey/Документы/008.jpeg

Comment: @IvanCheshkov. I've added it to your question. Please do that next time for a full [mcve]. Hopefully this teaches you why you need to provide complete information, not what you think is important. After all, if you knew what was important to begin with, you probably wouldn't be asking for help.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser. It is now.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945920/why-doesnt-os-path-join-work-in-this-case help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the filenames in `array` are absolute paths, this will not work. [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) will restart the filename from an absolute path. For example, on Windows `join('C:/x', 'C:/y')` results in `'C:/y'`. On Linux, `join('/x', '/y')` returns `'/y'`.

In your loop `file[:-len(srcSfx)] + destSfx` is an absolute path, so the intended prefix, `save_dir` is simply discarded. To avoid that, call to [`basename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) similarly to how you used [`dirname`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) when constructing `save_dir`:

```
p = os.path.join(save_dir, os.path.basename(file)[:-len(srcSfx)] + destSfx)
```

As a minor aside, I generally prefer to import the names like

```
from os.path import basename, dirname, join
```

In that case, the result is a bit shorter and easier to read:

```
save_dir = join(dirname(array[0]), "Converted_files")
...
    join(save_dir, basename(file)[:-len(srcSfx)] + destSfx)
```