# Django: STATIC_ROOT STATIC_ROOT can't join with BASE_DIR path

Tags: python, django, static, django-staticfiles, django-3.2

I want my STATIC_ROOT path to be at `F:/7.Django/BLOG_PROJECT/src_blog/' + '/vol/web/staticfiles` but django set it at `F:/vol/web/staticfiles`

I set up my STATIC_ROOT like this

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'/vol/web/staticfiles')

print('this is base_dir')
print(BASE_DIR)
print("this is static_root")
print(STATIC_ROOT)
```

When I run `python manage.py runserver` it print out this:

```
this is base_dir
F:\7.Django\BLOG_PROJECT\src_blog
this is static_root
F:/vol/web/staticfiles
this is base_dir
F:\7.Django\BLOG_PROJECT\src_blog
this is static_root
F:/vol/web/staticfiles
```

When I run `python manage.py collectstatic`. Sure! It set my STATIC_ROOT AT `F:/vol/web/staticfiles`. I noticed that it print out the separate folder symbol different '/' and #backslashsymbol. I use windows os btw.

Comment: what exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: there isn't any error. it just set Static_root path not where I wanted

Comment: so what is the desired result versus the current output?

Comment: My desired file path `F:/7.Django/BLOG_PROJECT/src_blog/vol/web/staticfiles` <br> And my current Static_root path `F:/vol/web/staticfiles`

Comment: you could try to first join the two paths as strings, and then convert it back to path object.
You should probably change `/` to ```\\``` to keep it consistent

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't os.path.join() work in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945920/why-doesnt-os-path-join-work-in-this-case)

Comment: You shouldn't be providing any slashes in your path if you want `os.path.join` to handle them properly, hence you should be writing `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'vol', 'web', 'staticfiles')`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat You're right. That's a lot better. <br> I was thinking about how to handle my local computer vs my container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! Just change it to a backlash-symbol instead of '/'. 
Look like just a window vs linux anoying thing.

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'vol\web\staticfiles')
```

edit: You know my answer above will create problem when you use your code in Linux base container
@AbdulAzizBarkat give me a better solution : 
You shouldn't be providing any slashes in your path if you want `os.path.join` to handle them properly, hence you should be writing

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'vol', 'web', 'staticfiles')
```

Comment: You forget that originally you had a _leading_ slash in your path, the backslash and slash don't really matter if you use the function properly.

Comment: `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'\vol\web\staticfiles')` give this output:F:\7.Django\BLOG_PROJECT\src_blog\ <br > <br />
ol\web\staticfiles
any way I edited my answer above: 
ol\web\staticfiles

Answer (score 0):

It probably solve your problem.

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'path'
```