# How to read a config file using python

Tags: python

I have a config file `abc.txt` which looks somewhat like:

```
path1 = "D:\test1\first"
path2 = "D:\test2\second"
path3 = "D:\test2\third"
```

I want to read these paths from the `abc.txt` to use it in my program to avoid hard coding.

Comment: Inventing your own formats, even if they look simple like that, is not the best idea generally. Better stick to a builtin one, there are plenty of choices: .ini, json, yaml, xml...

Comment: Related : [What's the best practice using a settings file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055042/)

Comment: Also see [Config files in Python](https://tutswiki.com/read-write-config-files-in-python/)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

In order to use my example, your file "abc.txt" needs to look like this.

```
[your-config]
path1 = "D:\test1\first"
path2 = "D:\test2\second"
path3 = "D:\test2\third"
```

Then in your code you can use the config parser.

```py
import ConfigParser

configParser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()   
configFilePath = r'c:\abc.txt'
configParser.read(configFilePath)
```

As [human.js](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1198898/human-js) noted in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379120/how-to-read-a-config-file-using-python#comment65311456_19379306), in Python 3, `ConfigParser` has been renamed `configparser`. See  [Python 3 ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser) for more details.

Comment: I've edited the post, my suggestion is for using config files it much easier and very useful, that way you can learn a new thing that can really help you. the error `MissingSectionHeaderError` was beacuse you need the section `[file]`

Comment: Certainly useful; did not know this before. +1

Comment: Hi @Kobi,  I'm having one doubt as well. I put my "abc.txt" inside the project folder and I do not want to give the absolute path here [configFilePath = r'c:\abc.txt']. Instead, I want only the absolute path to be assigned to the configFilePath so that even if I move my script to other machines, I don't have to change the path here containing the project workspace location, etc. Is there anyway to accomplish that ?

Comment: @user2882117 you are right that you want to use relative path (that's the correct name) instead of absolute path you can find a good solution in here [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7166139/1982962)

Comment: Thanks, but it's yielding me [error] NameError ( name '__file__' is not defined ) and in my previous comment I had a typo, actually I meant "Instead, I want only the relative path to be assigned to the..."

Comment: @KobiK I'm able to get the path of the currently executed script file by os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])). Then I could do an os.path.join with my "abc.txt". That solved the issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: NP:) that's a nice approach.

Comment: in python 3, ConfigParser is renamed to configparser. Check here for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser

Comment: it's better to call the file abc.ini

Comment: Great answer so +1. I wish the Python team would make up their minds as regards capitalisation!

Comment: You may want to remove quotes from your config file variables content since using configParser.get('your-config', 'path1') will add another stack of (single) quotes (tested on python3 configparser)

Comment: Hello, we are using configparser() to parse the config values in the code but the changes we make to the config.ini is not getting reflected. We have built the executable of our python app and along with the config.ini next to it. But it looks like it packaged the config.ini within the exe and not referencing the config file and its changes. how to handle that?

Answer (score 39):

You need a section in your file:

```
[My Section]
path1 = D:\test1\first
path2 = D:\test2\second
path3 = D:\test2\third
```

Then, read the properties:

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.readfp(open(r'abc.txt'))
path1 = config.get('My Section', 'path1')
path2 = config.get('My Section', 'path2')
path3 = config.get('My Section', 'path3')
```

Comment: readfp is deprecated. Use read_file instead: `config.read_file(open(r'abc.txt'))`

Comment: You can use even `config.read(r'abc.txt')`. See official [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read) for deatils.

Comment: In Python 3, ConfigParser has been renamed to configparser for PEP 8 compliance.

Answer (score 25):

If you need to read all values from a section in properties file in a simple manner:

Your `config.cfg` file layout :

```
[SECTION_NAME]  
key1 = value1  
key2 = value2
```

You code:

```
   import configparser

   config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
   config.read('path_to_config.cfg file')
    
   details_dict = dict(config.items('SECTION_NAME'))
```

This will give you a dictionary where keys are same as in config file and their corresponding values.

`details_dict` is :

```
{'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'}
```

Now to get key1's value :
`details_dict['key1']`

**Putting it all in a method which reads sections from config file only once(the first time the method is called during a program run).**

```
def get_config_dict():
    if not hasattr(get_config_dict, 'config_dict'):
        get_config_dict.config_dict = dict(config.items('SECTION_NAME'))
    return get_config_dict.config_dict
```

Now call the above function and get the required key's value :

```
config_details = get_config_dict()
key_1_value = config_details['key1']
```

---

---

***Generic Multi Section approach:***

```
[SECTION_NAME_1]  
key1 = value1  
key2 = value2  

[SECTION_NAME_2]  
key1 = value1  
key2 = value2
```

Extending the approach mentioned above, reading section by section automatically and then accessing by section name followed by key name.

```
def get_config_section():
    if not hasattr(get_config_section, 'section_dict'):
        get_config_section.section_dict = collections.defaultdict()
        
        for section in config.sections():
            get_config_section.section_dict[section] = dict(config.items(section))
    
    return get_config_section.section_dict
```

**To access:**

```
config_dict = get_config_section()

port = config_dict['DB']['port']
```

*(here **'DB'** is a section name in config file
and **'port'** is a key under section 'DB'.)*

Answer (score 6):

A convenient solution in your case would be to include the configs in a yaml file named
`**your_config_name.yml**` which would look like this:

```
path1: "D:\test1\first"
path2: "D:\test2\second"
path3: "D:\test2\third"
```

In your python code you can then load the config params into a dictionary by doing this:

```
import yaml
with open('your_config_name.yml') as stream:
    config = yaml.safe_load(stream)
```

You then access e.g. path1 like this from your dictionary *config*:

```
config['path1']
```

To import yaml you first have to install the package as such: `pip install pyyaml` into your chosen virtual environment.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like valid Python code, so if the file is on your project's classpath (and not in some other directory or in arbitrary places) one way would be just to rename the file to "abc.py" and import it as a module, using `import abc`. You can even update the values using the `reload` function later. Then access the values as `abc.path1` etc.

Of course, this *can* be dangerous in case the file contains other code that will be executed. I would not use it in any real, professional project, but for a small script or in interactive mode this seems to be the simplest solution.

Just put the `abc.py` into the same directory as your script, or the directory where you open the interactive shell, and do `import abc` or `from abc import *`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have a project build and all. I'm just running the Python script from commandline only. Is it possible to do something like this in this case ? I mean is there any other way to make these together as a package or something like that ?

Comment: @user2882117 Sure, just put the `abc.py` in the same directory as your script, or the directory you start an interactive shell in, and do `import abc`. Particularly if it's just for a small script, I think this is the simplest solution, but I would not use it in a "real" project.

Comment: You need to be careful with backslashes in strings.

Answer (score 3):

For Pyhon 3.X:

Notice the lowercase import configparser makes a big difference.

Step 1:

Create a file called "config.txt" and paste the below two lines:

```
 [global]
 mykey = prod/v1/install/
```

Step 2:

Go to the same directory and create a testit.py and paste the code  below into a file and run it. (FYI: you can put the config file anywhere you like you, you just have to change the read path)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(r'config.txt')   

print(config.get('global', 'mykey') )
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your config file is a normal text file, just read it using the `open` function:

```
file = open("abc.txt", 'r')
content = file.read()
paths = content.split("\n") #split it into lines
for path in paths:
    print path.split(" = ")[1]
```

This will print your paths. You can also store them using dictionaries **or** lists.

```
path_list = []
path_dict = {}
for path in paths:
    p = path.split(" = ")
    path_list.append(p)[1]
    path_dict[p[0]] = p[1]
```

More on reading/writing file [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).
Hope this helps!

Comment: Remember to `close` the file, or better, use a `with` block. And might as well put those into a dictionary.

Comment: Also, if it's just a text file, i would recommend to discard the quotes.

Comment: @tobias_k He can figure it out himself :)