# Python FLASK REST AUTH

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

MY following question:
How can i call auth username and password from a config file.

```
r = requests.get(url, auth=('username', 'password')).content
```

What i wish is 
a config file which include username, password

```
r = requests.get(url, auth=(MYconfig file)).content
```

hope any one can give me a sample.

thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a config file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379120/how-to-read-a-config-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you want to use the [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)
Your conf file looks like this:

```
[user.auth]
username = my
password = password
```

In your code you should use it like this :

```
import configparser


config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("C:\myconf\defaults.cfg")
```

then you should get your credentials like this:

```
username = config.get('user.auth', 'username')
password = config.get('user.auth', 'password')
```