# Is there any way to change the SQL Server name in Python code based on the environment?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, ssis, etl

In my Python script, I established the SQL Server DEV connection and I am calling this script in my SSIS package, so now I want to deploy the project on Production server.

Q: How SQL server connection should be changed to Production from Development automatically/dynamically without editing the script manually? Is there a way that it should get/read Production environment?

Please help me out with this, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`sys.argv` and pass it as a [command line parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117530/sys-argv1-meaning-in-script).

Pull it from an [environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python) value `os.environ`

Read from a config file with [configparser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379120/how-to-read-a-config-file-using-python)

Without any sample code, it's hard to say what the right approach should be but I would favor a command line parameter as that allows you to provide the value from the SSIS package (instead of defining configurations in both SSIS space and python space)