# Is there a way to parameterize magic commands in Databricks notebooks?

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I want to use be able to run through a list of config files and use %run to import variables from config files into a databricks notebook.
But I cant find a method to dynamically change the file following %run.

I have tried specifying a parameter like this:
config = './config.py'
%run $config
But it doesn't work. I cannot use dbutils.notebook.run(config) as I won't get access to the variables in my main notebook.

Can anything think of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since, you have already mentioned config files, I will consider that you have the config files already available in some path and those are not Databricks notebook.

You can use python - configparser in one notebook to read the config files and specify the notebook path using %run in main notebook (or you can ignore the notebook itself by using configparser in main notebook)

Reference: [How to read a config file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379120/how-to-read-a-config-file-using-python)

Comment: Can config parser parse  .py files?  I wan't to keep my config in .py files as there's some complex datatypes in there.  Usually this would be easy as you just >import config but you can't do that in Databricks, hence wanting to use %run. But I wan't to dynamically run through a different of config.py files depending on the use case. My best solution atm is keeping >%run Config.py static and dynamically renaming the other .py files to ./config.py, depending on which one I want to use.