# Passing inputs when importing?

Tags: python, filesystems

I'm working on a project where my code is spread across different files; for instance, in `convex.py`, I invoke methods I've written in `rings.py` by calling `from rings import *` at the top. In `rings` I define a constant `p` using `mpmath` which is used in the various functions of `rings`, so it depends on the precision I've hand-written into `rings` (e.g. via `mpmath.mp.dps = 40`). However, when using `convex` I may later on want `p` to have higher precision. Is there a way to make `rings` take in some input when I import it into `convex`? e.g. maybe I want 50 decimal digits of precision once, and 100 the next use, so a perfect solution would be to let `rings` take in an input `D` and set `mpmath.mp.dps = D` there, and in `convex` maybe have

```
D = 50
from rings[D] import *
```

(and then use `D` elsewhere in the file, and where I can also freely change `D` (along with whatever else I'd like to change in `convex`, without needing to go back into `rings` each time)). (The proposed notation above is to sort of view `rings` as a function of `D`.)

The only concrete workaround I see would be to modify each of my `rings` methods to take inputs as *all* of the precision-dependent constants which I've defined in `rings`, redefine them in `convex`, and then pass them as arguments; but this seems like a clunky and overall bad solution.

Let me know if I can clarify any of this. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Sample code

```
# rings.py
import mpmath as mp
from mpmath import sqrt
mp.mp.dps = 40
p = sqrt(2)
def f(x):
    return p*x
```

```
# convex.py
import mpmath as mp
from mpmath import sqrt
from rings import *
D = 50 # or 100
mp.mp.dps = D
q = sqrt(3)
print D+f(q)
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand your problem setup - maybe adding minimal code snippets would help. From what I've understood, if you want to change the value `D` when running `convex.py`, did you think about writing a class in `rings.py` and instantiating it in `convex.py` by setting the desired `D` value? Or maybe to keep a separate config file that can access in one of those scripts?

Comment: @akilat90 I've added simplified sample snippets in the main post. The main use of the constant-dependent code would be as functions, so I'm not certain making it into classes is optimal (though I'm also relatively new to classes so could be mistaken). How would I go about setting up this config file that you mention?

Comment: IIUC, you need to use the same (and arbitrary) `dps` value for all the calculations in both `convex.py` and `rings.py`. Since `mp.mps.dps` is a global variable, wouldn't it be sufficient to set that to an arbitrary value  in `convex.py` itself (like you're already doing)? [How to read config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379120/how-to-read-a-config-file-using-python), but it seems irrelevant.

Comment: @akilat90 To make sure I'm understanding correctly: globalness implies that if I compile `convex` with `mp.mp.dps = 50`, then this will supersede `mp.mp.dps = 40` in `rings` at time of compilation, including in the evaluation of `p`?

Comment: (I've just put together toy files and it confirms that the answer to the above question is yes)

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward solution in my head would be to declare a class, which allows to update the value `D`.

## rings.py

```
import mpmath as mp
from mpmath import sqrt

class Ring:
    def __init__(self, D=40):
        mp.mp.dps = D

    def set_d(self, D):
        mp.mp.dps = D

    def f(self, x):
        p = sqrt(2)
        return p * x
```

## convex.py

```
import mpmath as mp
from mpmath import sqrt
from rings import Ring

D = 50
ring = Ring(D)
q = sqrt(3)
print(D + ring.f(q))
```

I hope I understood your question correctly. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I think this does accomplish it, thank you. To double-check: one could move `p = sqrt(2)` into `__init__` in order for it to be used in another method of `Ring`, and it could then be accessed in `convex` as `ring.p`?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Classes and object are worth reading into if you are not that familiar yet. You will definitely find a lot of good guides online.