# How to get variable value inside the setup.cfg

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

I have some one ADO pipeline which builds and destributes my python client app. During the pipline two builds are created, one for STAGE and one for PROD. According this I need to build *my-project-stage* as a STAGE artifact and *my-project* as a PROD artifact. They are both from the same commit.
My question is how can I set and read variables inside the setup.cfg for the project name and for config file name (include stage app's config for NONPROD and prod app's config for the PROD build).

Something like this inside setup.cfg:
[image]

Is it possible? Or there is another way to do it?

Note: I don't use the setup.py in my project, but pyproject.toml (due to PEP-517 and PEP-518 compatibility)

Comment: Basically, a convoluted duplicate to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379120/how-to-read-a-config-file-using-python

Comment: @RoeyMichaeli Totally not. Your link is about the reading config/text files, but my question about dynamic customization the build process config

Comment: Which is basically, reading and writing a cfg. Read a cfg, get the variables, and change constants based on that. 
If I misunderstood, please elaborate.

Comment: @RoeyMichaeli not my code reads the setup.cfg, but the setuptools, so I can't controll this reading process and manipulate it. What I can to do it's just call *python -m build* and it automattically should build the project by setup.cfg configurations.