# File Directory error in python3

Tags: python-3.x, import, path, sys

For my program, I have 3 programs
They will all be listed bellow

C:\Python\data\fold1\subfile.py

```
import json
import sys

part = sys.path[0].split('\\')                  '''This part adds
del (part[part.index('Python') + 1:len(part)])     a system path
sys.path.insert(1, '\\'.join(part))                C:\Python'''

from data.fold2.other import accounts_list

class AddUser():
    def __init__(self, username, password, Type=1):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.Type = Type
        accounts_list[self.username] = [self.password, self.Type]
        with open('data\\fold2\\other.py', 'w') as file:
            file.write('accounts_list = ' + json.dumps(accounts_list))
```

C:\Python\data\fold2\start.py

```
import sys
from other import accounts_list

part = sys.path[0].split('\\')                 '''This part adds
del (part[part.index('Python') + 1:len(part)])    a system path
sys.path.insert(1, '\\'.join(part))               C:\Python'''

from data.fold1 import subfile

subfile.AddUser('username', 'password')
```

C:\Python\data\fold2\other.py

```
accounts_list = {}
```

When I run my main program, start, I get the error:

```
  File "C:\Python\data\fold1\subfile.py", line 16, in __init__
    with open('data\\fold2\\other.py', 'w') as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:                 'data\\fold2\\other.py'
```

I have no idea how to resolve this error as I am still a beginner. 
If anyone knows what to do, please provide an answer.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of opening files I would recommend to take a look at: [Open file in a relative location in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165749/open-file-in-a-relative-location-in-python) Otherwise, your problem is simply as stated above that you are trying to access a nonexisting file. To switch between subfolders just use `../fold2/other.py`.

Comment: I know the directory is not usually in the sys.path so I added it in the code?      And if the ... is C:\Python ect., I cant really add that as this program is on multiple different computers so it will be saved in different spots.

Comment: I also tried adding from ..data.fold2 ect. and get the error: SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

Comment: @Nic You are not changing you working directory. Do something similar to `os.chdir('/path/...')`. Though in my opinion it makes more sense to use relative dependencies.

Comment: What is relative dependencies? I am still a beginner at python.

Comment: From within a package, subdirectories are not included just like that; you need to "chain" the directories. (add a `__init__.py` file) In terms of relative dependencies just have a look at the link I posted.

Comment: Can you please give me some sort of an example with "chaining" the files and adding the init.py. That would be a real help! Thanks

Comment: Just include a `__init__.py` file in all your folders. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: Thanks! Ill figure it out. You saved my and my programs bacon :D Keep up the good work!