# Open a file in python from 2 directory back

Tags: python

I want to read a file from 2 folders back..

```
with open('../../test.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()
```

I want to read from  `../../` two folders back. but not work..
How i can do that ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath

Comment: what is the actual error?

Comment: This is very similar to the question answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7166139/13812770

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening files in python is relative to the current working directory. This means you would have to change `cd` to the directory where this python file is located.

If you want a more robust solution:

To be able to run this from any directory, there is a simple trick:

```py
import os

PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../../test.txt')
with open(PATH, 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()
```