# Why does VSCode terminal give "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a very simple directory:

```
-Project
   - Folder_1
     - data.csv
   - Folder_2
     - read_data.py
```

Inside read_data.csv, I simply want to read the data.csv file that's in Folder_1. To do that, I have to 'move up' in the directory and go into Folder_1 as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("../Folder_1/data.csv")

print(df)
```

When I run the read_data.py file, the terminal throws this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Obviously the file is there. Funny thing is, when I run this in an interactive window it runs fine (just like a notebook cell). Or if I run the python file in PyCharm, it's fine. I only get this error if I run it through the VSCode terminal.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Hi there Danny, welcome to StackOverflow, I noticed your question is missing format so I helped you to edit it. This is unrelated to your question, but you can format your questions/answers with markdown, you can learn the [basics of markdown here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Please take a look at this answer, it should help you to answer why you are facing this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7166139/2466342. You are most likely facing this problem because your terminal is currently set to `/c/some/path/Project/`. When your script uses **relative path** like `../Folder1/data.csv`, it actually means `/c/some/Folder1/data.csv`. You can google "Relative path vs absolute path" to learn more.

Comment: @terahertz thank you for the help. I see that VSCode integrated terminal is set to the working directory like you said. How do I set it to the current python file though? That seems to automatically be the case in PyCharm. Shouldn't this automatically happen when I 'Run Python File' in VScode?

Comment: Fixed: Extensions > Python > Terminal: Execute In File Dir.