# saving/creating a file in a relative path with python 3

Tags: python, string, file, python-3.x, path

I'm new to Python and i'd like to build a script (Python 3) to test electronic modules and save log files.
I'd like to save the logfiles in the following format:

```
201410log.txt (yearmonthlog.txt)
```

This is done with the code:

```
import os

logfile=open(time.strftime('%Y%mlog.txt'), 'a') 
logfile.write('This is a test\n\n\n')
```

This way, every month a new log file is created.
However, i'd like the logfiles to be in in a subdirectory (\logs).

I tried approaches like

```
logfile=open(time.strftime('\logs\%Y%mlog.txt'), 'a')
```

and similar things but i couldnt get any of them to work.
I searched trough other questions on stackoverflow (for example: [Relative paths in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python) ) and elsewhere in the internet, but i couldnt find the right solution. 
Could someone point me in the right direction?

(sorry for any mistakes/spelling errors, i'm no native english speaker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the leading backslash. It makes the path absolute. Beside that, you need to escape a backslash.

```
logfile = open(time.strftime('logs\\%Y%mlog.txt'), 'a')
```

or use `r'raw string literal'`:

```
logfile = open(time.strftime(r'logs\%Y%mlog.txt'), 'a')
```

For your current path string literal, it does not make problem. But paths like `'a\nb'` will not work because `\n` is interpreted as newline instead of a literal backslash and `n`.

Comment: thank you! this already solved my question. would it make any sense if i use `logfile = open(time.strftime(**r**'logs\\%Y%mlog.txt'), 'a')`