# Point Heroku application to AWS RDS database

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-rds

I need to point my Heroku application to my AWS RDS database. My RDS database is up and running and has a security group with 0.0.0.0/0 access.

Currently, I've removed my Heroku postgreSQL database and I am attempting to point my Heroku application to my RDS database. For some reason my application is crashing. The step that I believe I am on is setting my DATABASE_URL on the Heroku side.

Let's say that my database credentials are:

db instance: mydb 
dbname: mydb 
user: wcronyn 
pass: password

I've tried:

heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=postgres://wcronyn:password@mydb.XXXXXXX.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/mydb

and I've attempted to set the permissions by downloading the .pem file into my config folder and then referencing it:

DATABASE_URL=postgres://wcronyn:password@mydb.XXXXXXX.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/mydb?sslca=config/amazon-rds-ca-cert.pem&sslmode=require&encrypt=true

I have tried these two database urls but my application keeps crashing.

Can someone outline the steps that I need to take to successfully host my RDS database and point my application to it?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what to do here? I'm in a world of pain :(

Comment: @pseudopeach yes I did! I can walk you through it, but I'm busy for the day. I'll post tomorrow.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!!

Comment: Posted the answer below @pseudopeach Pardon the delay!

Comment: August 2020 - didn't need any certificate management. Just set Public accessibility to Yes on RDS, modified the security group and set the DATABASE_URL

Answer (score 36):

The following steps worked for me (Feb 2017), given the following setup:

- AWS RDS Region eu-west-2 (which uses VPC Security Groups, not DB
  Security Groups)
- Postgres 9.6
- Heroku, hosting a Flask application (eg appname: `heroku-app-stage`)
- Git with a remote added into the Heroku app (eg remote: `stage`)
- DATABASE_URL value of `postgresql://username:password@awsrdshost:5432/dbname`

There are broadly four steps to this:

1. Download and install the Amazon RDS SSL root certificate into your Heroku app
2. Configure your Heroku app to refer to said root certificate
3. Enable SSL on your RDS instance
4. Configure your RDS security group to allow all IP address ranges for Incoming traffic

**Download and install Amazon RDS SSL root certificate**

1. Download the .pem certificate file from the Amazon RDS link below.
2. Put the file into your app folders (make a note of location, I have placed it in my root folder with my .py files)
3. Commit that file into your git repository, and push said commit into the Heroku remote (`git push stage master`)
4. Verify that the certificate has been uploaded into the expected path (you can do `heroku run bash --app heroku-app-stage` to see your files in the dyno)

**Configure Heroku to refer to root certificate**

1. Via the Heroku dashboard, navigate to `heroku-app-stage`, go to Settings tab, and click on Reveal Config Vars
2. Update your DATABASE_URL variable by adding `?sslrootcert=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&sslmode=require`. The new value should now be `postgresql://username:password@awsrdshost:5432/dbname?sslrootcert=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&sslmode=require`

Note that this answer uses a root certificate; there may be other options which may be what you want in which case refer to the following SO:

[How to connect to a remote PostgreSQL database with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28228241/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-postgresql-database-with-python)

**Enable SSL on your RDS instance**

1. Via your RDS console, navigate to your instance details and note down the Parameter Group that it is using
2. Go to the Parameter Group screen on the dashboard
3. If you are using the default parameter group, you will need to create another parameter group, as you will not be able to edit the default one.
4. Modify the force_ssl parameter to have value 1 and save.
5. Verify that SSL is now enabled on your RDS instance. If you run `psql postgres -h awsrdshost -p 5432 -U username`, you should see SSL in the connection details

**Configure RDS security group to allow all incoming IP ranges**

1. Via your RDS console, check the active Security Group for your instance
2. Navigate to the EC2 console (under Compute > EC2), and select Security Groups
3. Select the relevant security group (from step 1) and go to the Inbound tab at the bottom. You should see a PostgreSQL item listed there. If you hit Edit, you should have an option to change the Source to Anywhere.

Note: instructions are only relevant if you're using an RDS setup that uses VPC Security Groups

That's it!

Links to the reference pages used:

Amazon's guide to SSL on Postgres
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL

Heroku's (very short) guide to Amazon RDS
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/amazon-rds

Comment: That's `rds.force_ssl` now instead of `force_ssl`.

Comment: is the only way to allow all incoming ip ranges? i see attempts at connecting to the db via unauthorized users

Comment: @MattKim you can restrict the IP address range only if you are able to fix the Heroku application's source IP address. This isn't something they offer out of the box (unlike Elastic IPs on AWS, for example) but certainly something you can provision via an add-on like Fixie.

Comment: I did this to update my cert on RDS (March 2020 deadline). Note that right when you update your `DATABASE_URL` to force SSL and use new cert, your Heroku app will not be able to talk to RDS until RDS has been updated to use the 2019 CA.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out how to point heroku app to AWS RDS database. This allows me to have a giant database, test out Amazon's free tier for a year and have more customization over my database instance. This answer is in response to @pseudopeach question (pardon the delay).

So this is a pretty simple set up. To configure RDS for Heroky you need to know heroku well and you need to know AWS VERY well.

1. AWS side

a) set up your region. Pick the region closest to you e.g. US EAST (Ohio)

b) then click services tab and select rds

c) i have a db ts micro (i think that's the free tier option)

d) do the rds set up and after it is up and running you click "instance actions" and see details

e) here you will be able to view your db-username, dbname, endpoint (which for me is a url similar to this [dbname].[randomstring].us-east-1.rds.amazon.com) and port number. You need these things plus you db password for the heroku side.

2. Heroku side

a) go to your heroku app on heroku.com, then settings
b) click revealconfig variables

typical heroku variables look like this:

DATABASE_URL                        xxxxxx

HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_VIOLET_URL        xxxxxx

LANG                                xxxxxx

RACK_ENV                            production

RAILS_ENV                           production

SECRET_KEY_BASE                     xxxxxx

you need to do change these up pretty drastically

DATABASE_URL [note: this changes to a different and long url – mine looks like this broken down for easy understanding]

postgres://

[db-username]:

[your db password]

@[endpoint]:

[your db port number]/

[db name]

?sslca=config/amazon-rds-ca-cert.pem

&sslmode=require

&encrypt=true

example database url:
postgres://jdoe:supersecretpassword@mydb.coua7574xvna.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/mydb?sslca=config/amazon-rds-ca-cert.pem&sslmode=require&encrypt=true

EXTERNAL_DATABASE           amazon-rds-ca-cert.pem

EXTERNAL_DATABASE_CA        amazon-rds-ca-cert.pem

LANG                        (same)

RACK_ENV                    (same)

RAILS_ENV                   (same)

RDS_DB_PASS                 [your db password]

RDS_DB_PORT                 [your db port number i.e. 5432]

RDS_READS_DB_NAME           [db name]

RDS_HOST                    [end point url]

RDS_USER                    [db-username]

This worked for me and I got a free year of RDS for a database way over 10,000 rows (which I believe is the free tier limit on heroku). I used postgreSQL as my database, so these configs might be biased toward postgres.

Comment: See this post for Best Practices on using RDS database with Heroku App https://vel-lesikov.medium.com/migrating-from-heroku-postgres-to-amazon-rds-2e738e7730e5

Answer (score 1):

I did exactly the same that Andy G answer said.

However I ran into the following error:

no pg_hba.conf entry for host "XX.XX.XX.XX", user "username", database "dbname", SSL off

To fix this issue on **Configure Heroku to refer to root certificate** step 2:

Instead of adding `?sslrootcert=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&sslmode=require`

add `?ssl=true&sslrootcert=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&sslmode=require`