# Error TypeOrmModule Unable to connect to database with "ETIMEDOUT" or "Handshake inactivity timeout"

Tags: mysql, node.js, nestjs, typeorm, amazon-aurora

I have a [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) (v8.2.x) server application which I'm attempting to connect to an AWS Arura 3.x (MySQL 8.x protocol) using [TypeORM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeorm) (v0.2.41) and either the [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) (v2.18.1) or [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) (v2.3.3) driver. The application is running in a GitHub Codespace.

When following the [NestJS TypeORM documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database) I'm getting the following errors:

With `mysql2` driver I'm getting:

```
ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
 Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
 ...
```

With `mysql` driver I'm getting:

```
[TypeOrmModule] Error: Handshake inactivity timeout
 ...
```

The code creating the connection looks as follows:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

const MYSQL_HOST = '....rds.amazonaws.com';
const MYSQL_USERNAME = '...';
const MYSQL_PASSWORD = '...';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: MYSQL_HOST,
      port: 3306,
      username: MYSQL_USERNAME,
      password: MYSQL_PASSWORD,
      database: 'kitchen',
      // entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      debug: true,
      logging: true,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

### Initial Troubleshooting

First, I validated the credentials I'm utilizing in the server application. I affirmed they worked correctly to connect via [TablePlus](https://www.tableplus.io/). Thus, I ruled out "invalid credentials" and determined I had another issue.

Secondly, when creating the AWS Arura database I'd selected **Yes** to **Public Access**:

> Amazon EC2 instances and devices outside the VPC can connect to your database. Choose one or more VPC security groups that specify which EC2 instances and devices inside the VPC can connect to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Fix

TL;DR: Although, I'd selected **Yes** to **Public Access** I had to further relax the "inbound" security rules it seems. Thus, adding another "inbound rule" with `source: "0.0.0.0/0"` resolved my issue.

## Debug

Why? Maybe because the default rule of `source: "76.202.164.21/32"` doesn't work because of where the GitHub Codespace is hosted? No idea...

How did I find this?

Initially, I was using the `mysql2` package and getting it's error (listed above) with no StackOverflow results. As `mysql2` is a "drop in replacement" for the basic `mysql` package I decided to revert to `mysql` to see if it had a different error. As listed above, I received a slightly different error which lead me to StackOverflow question [Error: Handshake inactivity timeout in Node.js MYSQL module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553432/error-handshake-inactivity-timeout-in-node-js-mysql-module). Where there are AWS specific answers:

a) [mscheker's `add an inbound rule`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58418558/6480404)

> For those deploying on `AWS` and experiencing this error, you'll need to make a change to the security group of your database/cluster and `add an inbound rule` where the `source` is the **security group of your instance/s**.

b) [Berkay Torun's "changing the allowed IP Addresses"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55419741/6480404)

> If you are using Amazon's services, I was able to resolve this by changing the allowed IP Addresses in the security settings or by changing the open connections ports.

are what I followed to resolve the issue. Adding an extra inbound rule of "all IPv4 address" are allowed via `source: "0.0.0.0/0"`.

Answer (score 0):

**In my case I had to add the entity in forFeature to the module**

[image]