# How to add MongoDB in Metabase which has ca-certificate for authentication

Tags: mongodb, ca, metabase

I am using the [Metabase](https://www.metabase.com/) tool for data visualization.

I was trying to connect to a local MongoDb instance which doesn't have a certificate and it went successfully.

Now I want to connect to a MongoDb instance which has ca-certificate file required for connection (because it allows only TLS 1.2 connections). But I Don't know how to configure it in Metabase.

Below is the screen shot of what I tried.

[image: Metabase database connection setup]

How do I connect from Metabase to a DB if it involves ca-certificate?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a [look at this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247347/point-heroku-application-to-aws-rds-database), which details obtaining and utilizing an AWS cert.