# Django is .using() method safe?

Tags: django, database, python-3.x, security, django-models

im currentl working on a project where i have a django app on Server A with its own Database "default" and this app comunicates in some instances with another databse "not-default" on Server B.

In the latest version of this Service the app retrieves "non-critical" Data from the "non-default" database via the `.using("non-default")` Queryset method. But now i face the challenge to also retrieve or update critical User data from this database.

So I#m now unsure how safe a Query to this "non-default" database is when performing it with the `.using()` method.

Now the Question:

Is the process of sending a Query via `.using()` Querymethod safe?

And how is it protected ?

Comment: what do you mean by "how safe a Query to this "non-default" database", why you want to safe a query you should protect/encrypt data , try saving data in binary fields or some other encrypt way

Comment: protect database password in setting file properly , store password in os.environment variable instead of hard-coded value

Comment: @Vaibhav I want to know, in general, how the Query is (as u stated) encrypted on default by django.

Comment: I edited my Question to claryfy what is unlcear.

Comment: security is for connection / connector between database-server and Host-server, read this for more on connections https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#connection-management

Comment: Are you trying to encrypt the connection between the web server and database? If you're using PostgreSQL then this answer might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28228241/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-postgresql-database-with-python

Comment: @Andrew I'm firstly interessted in how the connection (as Vaibhav mentioned) is secured on default.