# Connection issue from Lambda to RDS PostgreSQL 15

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, postgresql-15

In RDS PotgreSQL 12, I can connect to DB using psycopg2 from local and also from Lambda function.
But when I upgrade to RDS PotgreSQL 15, I cannot connect to DB from Lambda anymore (I still can connect from local though).
The error that Lambda gives is:

```
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host ***, user ***, database ***, no encryption
```

This is how I connect:

```py
import psycopg2
connection_psql = psycopg2.connect(user=***
                                    , password=***
                                    , port="5432"
                                    , database=***
                                    , host=***)
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to enable ssl in the connection: [How to connect to a remote PostgreSQL database through SSL with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28228609/174777)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that in Lambda I was using a version of psycopg2 without ssl (from [this](https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2) repo). Apparently in recent versions of Postgres, ssl is required. The same repo has versions with ssl as well. Using those resolved the issue.

Comment: Thx for this comment. the "with_ssl" version stops at python 3.8.  did you find a solution to use a more recent python version ?

Comment: Found another repo with python 3.9 version build with SSL : https://github.com/anuragdev101/psycopg2