# Reference an Image Other Package in Python

Tags: python, pyqt

In my project i used this mechanism .

```
view/
   __init__.py
   forms/
      __init__.py
      someFile.py
   images/
      __init__.py
      someImage.png
```

I try display image in someFile.py to reference someImage.png . I try several of this :

```
 self.label_8.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("/view/images/someImage.png")))
 self.label_8.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("view/images/someImage.png")))
 self.label_8.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("images/someImage.png")))
 self.label_8.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("someImage.png")))
```

but i could not display the image . How can I fix that ?

Comment: This problems looks like it could be solved with the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python

Comment: Looks like you need the relative path. `..` points to the parent directory.

Comment: The problem is  like @dpwilson says relative path .. points . I fix it . Thank u again