# Give relative path of file in csv python

Tags: python, csv, hyperlink

I am creating a `csv` file in which i need to give hyperlinks to files in the same folder of `csv` file.

I have tried with absolute url like `=HYPERLINK("file:///home/user/Desktop/myfolder/clusters.py")` and its working fine.But can i given the relative path like
`=HYPERLINK("file:///myfolder/clusters.py")` because that is what my project required.User will download this csv along with some other files into his machine.So i cant give the absolute path of other files in csv.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative paths in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python)

Comment: `file:///` starts an absolute path. Two slashes are for the uri pattern and the thirds is the root of the filesystem. Try to use only two slashes.

Comment: I have updated the question.What my requirement is something different@McGrady

Comment: Did you try to remove a slash?

Answer (score 0):

For HYPERLINK you need use only absolute url