# Python utility fails to successfully run a non-Python script that uses relative paths

Tags: python, python-3.x, relative-path, absolute-path, os.system

My Python3 utility has a function that doesn't work (unless it's placed within selected directories, where it can then run the non-python `pdflatex` scripts successfully).  I want to run the utility from a set location on any of the template.tex files I have, stored in various other locations.

The Python utility prompts the user to select a `pdflatex` template file from an absolute path using a tkinter.filedialog GUI, then runs the user's selected `pdflatex`script using, for example: `os.system("pdflatex /afullpath/a/b/c/mytemplate.tex")`

Python's `os.system` runs `pdflatex`, which then runs its `mytemplate.tex` script.  `mytemplate.tex` has numerous inputs written with relative paths like `./d/another.tex`.

So, the Python utility works fine as long as it's in the exact same path as  `/afullpath/a/b/c/mytemplate.tex` that the user selects.  Otherwise `pdflatex` can't finds its own input files.  `pdflatex` delivers an error message like: `! LaTeX Error: File ./d/another.tex not found` because the execution path is relative to the Python script and not the `pdflatex` script.

[`pdflatex` needs to use relative paths because the folders with its .tex files get moved around, as needed.]

I found the following similar case on Stack Overflow, but I don't think the answers are geared towards this situation: [Relative Paths In Python -- Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By referring to other files with relative paths like `./d/another.tex`, your `mytemplate.tex` file is assuming (and requiring) that `pdflatex` is only run on it from the same directory that `mytemplate.tex` is located in.  You thus need to satisfy this requirement by changing to the directory containing `mytemplate.tex` before calling `os.system`:

```
input_file = '/afullpath/a/b/c/mytemplate.tex'
olddir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(input_file))
os.system('pdflatex ' + input_file)
os.chdir(olddir)
```

Even better is to use [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), as it handles the change of directory for you and isn't vulnerable to shell quoting issues:

```
subprocess.call(['pdflatex', input_file], cwd=os.path.dirname(input_file))
```

Comment: I don't think changing Python's own working directory is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use `subprocess.run` instead of `os.system` and pass in the `cwd` parameter as the directory of the latex script.

See the [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) docs here, and look at the `cwd` parameter for `subprocess.Popen`.

Example:

```
subprocess.run(["pdflatex", "/afullpath/a/b/c/mytemplate.tex"], cwd="/afullpath/a/b/c/")
```