# Pillow : File not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I would like to use images with tkinter's canvas but I can't open image with Pillow. In fact, I have all my images in the same folder as my code but when I put "icon.png" it doesn't work. Then when I put the full path to the image (C:/Users/myName/Desktop/PythonWork/game/src/icon.png) , it works.

`File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2312, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'icon.png'`

Therefore my question is : How do I make the relative path to work ?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: relative paths _are_ working -- paths are relative to the current working directory, not the directory where the script is. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/918154/7432

Comment: @BryanOakley he means relative the script which is a valid point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to reference files in the same directory as in Image.py, put this in Image.py:

```
import os

# get the directory path of the current python file
my_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

You can then append to that path the name of the file you want to access.