# How to access a data file of a Python package

Tags: python

Suppose I have a small Python package:

```
/mypack
/mypack/__init__.py
/mypack/mod1.py
/mypack/mod2.py
/mypack/table.csv
```

If I need something from mod1 in mod2, I can easily do a relative import:

```
# mod2.py
from .mod2 import something
```

This package can be copied to and accessed from anywhere and will work right away.

Now suppose I also need that `/mypack/table.csv` in `mod2`.

**How can I access that file in a way that will work no matter from where I access the module or to where I might copy it?**

Two remarks:

- Without the data file, I just need to copy the folder. I'd like to
  maintain that capability, instead of using deployment tools. (Because
  I currently rsync the Python code to several remote computers and
  just run it there. Not very convenient if more tools would come into
  play.)
- There's the option to query the path of a source file with the `os`
  package. But this doesn't seem to be fully portable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative paths in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

From an imported module, the special variable `__file__` is the path of the module. It is optional (not defined in an interactive Python session) but it should work in your use case.

So what you need from mod2 module is :

```
csv_path = os.path.join(dirname(__file__), 'table.csv')
```

From outside of the module, you could use:

```
csv_path = os.path.join(dirname(mod2.__file__), 'table.csv')
```