# How to make the path to songs in pygame relative

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, relative-path

Im working on a simple Snake game in python, and its working as intended here at home, but when I put the code on github, it doesn't find the path to the songs, I want to make this path relative, intead of absolute so it works on every computer.

Here is the part of the code for the song files -

```
 def game_sound(s):
        """ Include the game sfx and music"""
        if s == 0:
            pygame.mixer.music.load("background.ogg")
            pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
        elif s == 1:
            pygame.mixer.Sound("eating.wav").play()
        elif s == 2:
            pygame.mixer.Sound("game-over.wav").play()
```

TL - DR- It works here at home and nowhere else, Im trying to find a way to fix that by making the path relative I just dont know how. Can someone help?

Comment: maybe check here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/918154/7766131

Comment: didnt work @swimingduck, thanks anyway

Comment: if you run code in different folder than game folder then you have to find full path to game folder and join to song files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard method is to find real path to folder with application

```
import os, sys

APP_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
```

And later use it to create real path to file

```
full_path = os.path.join(APP_FOLDER, "eating.wav")

pygame.mixer.Sound(full_path).play()
```

Or you have to change `"current working directory"` (CWD) to application folder.

```
os.chdir(APP_FOLDER)

pygame.mixer.Sound("eating.wav").play()
```

You can check current working directory with

```
print(os.getcwd())
```

---

**BTW:** without this method problem is not only when you run on different computer but also when you run from different folder on the same computer - so it makes problem when you create shortcut/icon on desktop which executes program as `python game_folder/game.py`