# Create excel file using xlsxwriter in another folder using relative path

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I have a python file on path: ...Desktop/Python_files/python_file.py

I want to create an excel file stored on path: ...Desktop/Excel_files/exceL_file.xlsx

I want to do this using a relative path. This means that I want to step back from Python_files, go into Excel_files and create exceL_file.xlsx.
The syntax below is not working for this. How should I modify it?

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(' ../Excel_files/exceL_file.xlsx')
```

I am using python 2.7.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python Have you tried this?

Comment: You need to tell your script what it's working directory is
[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory

Answer (score 0):

```
import os.path

path=os.path.relpath("Your Path/Excel_files/exceL_file.xlsx")

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(path)
```

You can use os.path to get your relative path just replace  "Your Path" with your full path