# How can i read a file as relative path in Python with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code

File not found error occurs when reading a file as **relative path** in **Visual Studio Code**.
The file is currently in the same folder as the python script.
The same script is read successfully by running it in the Visual Studio.

How can i fix it so It can be read a file as relative path in Visual Studio Code?

Here my python script:

```
import numpy as np
file_name = 'file.csv'
xy = np.loadtxt(file_name, delimiter=',') # File not found error occured in Visual Studio Code
```

My OS is Windows.

Comment: which python you're using? python 2 or python 3?

Comment: This is correct code to "read a file as relative path". Obviously you need to understand what the path is relative too (which depends how you launch that code)... So not exactly clear what you are asking about.

Comment: @huynhsamha It's Python 3 (3.5.2)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I changed it as you said^^

Comment: @hyunjin-Kim your code work anyway, please try again https://imgur.com/ZZdqN3n

Comment: @huynhsamha Maybe it's the setting problem. I don't know what the problem is. my error : https://imgur.com/a/KbVvch2

Comment: @hyunjin-Kim maybe you're using on Windows, please reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python, it can help you

Comment: maybe you should check the script execution path.

Answer (score 0):

It is always safe to use the `os` module for file-paths. The following code prints the current directory and the complete path of the `file.csv` if it exists in that directory.

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()  # get current working dir: C:\\Users\\%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop
print("My current working directory is: {} ".format(cwd))
#search if the file exists in this directory
for file in os.listdir(cwd):
    if file.startswith("file"):
        print("File \"{}\" is located at \"{}\"".format(file, os.path.join(cwd, file)))
```

If the file is found in the directory, use the complete path and store it in a variable as a raw string or using `os.path.join()`. Eg.:

```
file_name = r"C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file.csv" #raw string
```

or

```
file_name = os.path.join(cwd, "file.csv") #join current working directory with the file.csv
```

Both will show the complete path as `C:\\Users\\%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop\\file.csv`.

To print all csv files (with their paths) in the directory, use `file.endswith(".csv")`.