# Upload Images through Url in selenium Webdriver using Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='upl-zone']/input").send_keys("https://ercess.com//images//events//-Blockchain-2019-36613-banner.png")
```

Is there any way to make that work ?

> [ERROR] selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: File not found: https://ercess.com//images//events//-Blockchain-2019-36613-banner.png

Comment: When i type url in windows explorer when uploading manually it works

Comment: I have deleted my answer.Any specific reason to do that. ```driver.get(url)``` also work right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to download the image to your computer and then upload it...

You can use `requests`:

```
import requests

URL = "https://ercess.com//images//events//-Blockchain-2019-36613-banner.png"
picture_req = requests.get(URL)
if picture_req.status_code == 200:
    with open("/path/to/image.jpg", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(picture_req.content)
```

Then send the `/path/to/image.jpg`:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='upl-zone']/input").send_keys("/path/to/image.jpg")
```

---

Or you can use the [`Legacy interface`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html?highlight=request#legacy-interface) of `urllib` you will use `urlretrieve`:

```
import urllib.request

URL = "https://ercess.com//images//events//-Blockchain-2019-36613-banner.png"
urllib.urlretrieve(URL, "file_name.png")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='upl-zone']/input").send_keys("file_name.png")
```

**EDIT:**

To send the path to the file with send_keys you can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#methods)

```
from pathlib import Path

# `cwd`: current directory is straightforward
cwd = Path.cwd()
# using "F"string for format you can use: image_file_name = str(cwd) + "\" + "file_name.png" 
image_file_name = fr"{cwd}\file_name.png"
# this print is just to show the image_file_name   
print(image_file_name)
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: it shows me error:
Message: File not found: file_name.png

Comment: what are you using? `urllib` or `requests`?

Comment: i am using urlib.urlretrieve @Moshe

Comment: The file is downloaded in the directory from where i am running but when i am trying to upload it tells me the error above @Moshe

Comment: ok but can i work with relative path because file will run on different computers in different locations, or should i download files in computer temporary folder, will it be a good idea ?

Comment: @Nitish I am not by a computer... But see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/918178/8179099

Comment: Hi @Nitish I just added the current way to use the path... see my edit...