# Using relative path in python after converting .command file (macos)

Tags: python, pandas

I converted my python project to a .command file on mac. I was using relative paths to import various CSV files as follow:

```
import pandas as
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
```

It works perfectly since the code and the csv are in the same directory.

Now I converted the python project into a .command executable file by using the following method:

Added first line of Python script as `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Changed the extension of the file to .command

In Terminal used command chmod +x Test.command

The relative paths don't work anymore and I have to enter the entire path. How can make the paths relative again?

Comment: Seems for me this is an Mac OS releated problem on linux this will work files relativ to current working directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use OS library

```
import os
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(dirname, 'path/where/to/go')
```

here it was answered for you:
[Relative paths in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python)

Comment: I get the following on doing this: `NameError: name '__file__' is not defined`

Comment: Go to the link i have gave, that guy has explained it