# Problem with path python, how can i solve it?

Tags: python, path

I have a script that I want to run everywhere, on any computer, regardless of where my files are placed

I saw some same question there but it wont solved my problem

I have some variables with path writed like this:

```
filePath = "C:\ProgramData\OutilTestObjets3D\MaquetteCB-2019\DataSet\ONLYIVENOTFIXED.txt"
```

how I can make it work like script work whenever  my folder "outilTestObjets3D" is, and not only in the c:ProgramData....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative paths in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python)

Comment: what's the expected path to your script and how it relates to .txt location?

Comment: there is the path to my script : C:\ProgramData\OutilTestObjets3D\MaquetteCB-2019\DataSet\DIAGTOOL\diagnosticTool.py 

its in the same directory of my .txt location

Comment: @OlehRybalchenko

Comment: I'd suggest reading about ["current working directories"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45591428/1358308), i.e. you shouldn't be referencing "absolute paths", just "relative paths".  google should be able to suggest lots of docs/tutorials from these keywords