# How to pass a file in sub-folder as parameter to a function in python

Tags: python

excerpt from my python script located at ***C:\Users\my_name\documents\python_projects\randomness\random.py*** :

```
some_number = 3452342
filename = str(some_number) + '.csv'

# file 3452342.csv is stored in C:\Users\my_name\documents\python_projects\randomness\history
# call a function that takes the filename as the parameter

my_func(r'history\filename')
```

It triggers the following error:

***FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'history\filename' does not exist: b'history\filename'***

what exactly is going wrong here?
How can I pass the filename to my_func when it is located in a sub-folder?

thanks in advance

Comment: You are passing the path `history\filename` as the path while filename is a variable. Try `my_func(f'history\{filename}')` instead. The `{}` will pass the value of `filename` instead of the string `filename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question what's going wrong:
Python tried to open the file with the name literally `"filename"` in the subdirectory named `"history"`, which is doesn't exist. You should pass the `filename` variable's value instead as follows:

You should use [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

```
import os

some_number = 3452342
filename = str(some_number) + '.csv'
workdir = "C:\Users\my_name\documents\python_projects\randomness\history"

my_func(os.path.join(workdir, filename))
```

Or if the file `3452342.csv` placed in a subfolder (called `history`) of the the main script's directory, then you can use:

```
import os

some_number = 3452342
filename = str(some_number) + '.csv'

my_func(os.path.join("history", filename))
```

Alternatively you can simply use string concatenation:

```
import os

some_number = 3452342
filename = str(some_number) + '.csv'

my_func("history/" + filename)
```

Another approach using Python's [format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting):

```
import os

some_number = 3452342
filename = str(some_number) + '.csv'

my_func("history/{}".format(filename))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, to be platform independent you should use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to concatenate directories.

Second, like @k88 pointed out, you need to pass the variable `filename` into your path, not the string `'filename'`

The clean way would be:

```
import os

some_number = 3452342
filename = str(some_number) + '.csv'

# file 3452342.csv is stored in C:\Users\my_name\documents\python_projects\randomness\history
# call a function that takes the filename as the parameter

my_func(os.path.join('history', filename))
```

### Relative Or Absolute Path?

If your history subfolder is a fixed subfolder of your script's directory, you should even consider to determine your target filename as an absolute path like this (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/918178/3104974) answer with comments):

```
base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
my_func(os.path.join(base_dir, 'history', filename))
```

Answer (score 1):

First try to get the current path then join the path you got with the name of your file.

```
import os

some_number = 3452342
filename = str(some_number) + '.csv'

path_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename)

my_func(path_file)
```

for more about how to work with path using python  check out this.
[Common pathname manipulations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)

Comment: If `os.getcwd()` or `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` should be used a base path depends on the desired logic of the code.

Comment: exactly he asked to get the path in the same sub folder.

Comment: Then IMHO `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` should be preferred, since `os.getcwd()` might change during runtime, or might even start off different if the script were be imported as a module from another directory.

Comment: yep at that point you are right! the best way is to allow the user set the path because the path might change on the runtime