# relative paths in python modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I am writing a python library with the following file structure:

```
main_folder
    |
    main.py
    |
    module_subfolder/
    |    |
    |   module.py
    |
    resources/
         |
        credential.txt
```

in `main.py` there is the following function:

```
def connect():
    cred_fp = 'resources/credential.txt' #note this path is relative 
    client = connect_to_client(cred_fp)

    return client
```

In `module.py` I have the following import statement and function:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(absolute/path/to/main.py)

import main

def do_thing_with_client():
    client = main.connect()
    #does thing
    print('done doing thing')
```

When I run module.py on its own for testing purposes, I get `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'resources/credential.txt'`

I fixed the problem by changing the file path in `main.py` to an absolute path, but it feels like there should be a way to keep the path relative, which I need to do. I am new to the process of creating well-organized and portable libraries/modules.

Comment: `cred_fp = 'resources/credential.txt'`  to `cred_fp='../resources/credential.txt'`

Comment: Does this previous answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python