# Store Excel file along within flask app and make it readable when deployed on heroku

Tags: python-3.x, flask, heroku

My flask app reads an locally stored excel file and it is running perfect on local machine.

When I deploy the same app on `heroku` it is throws exception-

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/QuestionBank_v5.xlsx'
```

Which is valid as heroku deployment cannot read from my local machine.

Is there a way to store this file along with flask app files and make it readable when deployed on heroku?

Comment: You need to use relative path to file and not a static absolute path. Note that heroku server and your local system are too different machines at two different places. Check here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store the file in the same directory as the Flask app file and use os.path to get the app's current directory and append the file name to it.

```
import os

# Current directory for Flask app
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Current directory for Flask app + file name
# Use this file_path variable in your code to refer to your file 
file_path = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'QuestionBank_v5.xlsx')

print(file_path)
```