# c++ call python script failed, when the called scipt import another script

Tags: python, c++

I want to call a python scipt *sayhello.py* which located at *D:/semantic_segmentation/scripts* in my c++ program, here is my c++ code:

```
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('D:/semantic_segmentation/scripts')");
PyObject* pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("sayhello");
```

the code of sayhello.py is:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
import a

def _sayhello(x):
    print('hello')
    return x

_sayhello(1)
```

When I run my C++ program the function *PyImport_ImportModule* returns NULL, but when I run *sayhello.py* with `python -m sayhello.py` directly it works fine. How can i fix this?

**edit**:
I found the problem is in the following code:

```
sys.path.append("..")
import a
```

the c++ program doesn't work when i import other script in *sayhello.py*. But when i move *a.py* to the same path with *sayhello.py*, and import *a.py* only with `import a`, my c++ program works. So my question is, how can i make my c++ program calling python script work, when the called script calls another script which located in other path?

Comment: what is `import a`?

Comment: it is another script a.py, which is located at *D:/semantic_segmentation*. If i remove ```import a```, i can run my c++ praogram successfully. It turns out that when i import other scripts in *sayhello.py*, my c++ program doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your python code assumes the current working directory of the process is the `D:/semantic_segmentation/scripts` directory, which is not necessarily the case.

Here are two solutions:

- change the working directory of your c++ program with `chdir` or the windows equivalent, or
- change the python code to compute an absolute path starting from the script file instead of the current working directory. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/918178/154846).