# Find users program path in program files for installation to correct directory

Tags: python, operating-system, filepath

So here is what I am trying to do.

I have a small program, which makes use of the pygame music player to play an mp3. I have this mp3 in the same directory as my python based exe, so I can run it.

The problem is I have the path to the mp3 specified as a 'SOUND_FILE =' string as shown below:

```
pygame.init()
SOUND_FILE = r'C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\herprogram\classical.mp3'

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
pygame.mixer.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load(SOUND_FILE)
pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
```

This means when I run an installation wizard on a different machine, the path to the mp3 will be wrong. It will have some other path/username.

The first part of the path I need to be dynamic, so I can concatenate it to the other half of the path I will specify in the installation wizard using an f string.

I have had a look at the python os module, but can't quite get my head around how to implement this.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks, Michael

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative paths in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python)

Comment: thanks I will take a look at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.getlogin()` to get the username for the user executing the file.

Or else if you want to get the location of the directory where the file is being executed, you can use `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`.

Here's the documentation for [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html) in case you want to look into it more.

Answer (score 1):

if the mp3 file it's supposed to be on the Desktop of the user's machine you can go:

```
from pathlib import Path

SOUND_FILE = f'{Path.home()}\Desktop\herprogram\classical.mp3'
```

Comment: It's not supposed to be Desktop; it's going to be in their program files (x86) folder.