# Finding a file in the same directory as the python script (txt file)

Tags: python

```
file = open(r"C:\Users\MyUsername\Desktop\PythonCode\configure.txt")
```

Right now this is what im using. However if people download the program on their computer the file wont link because its a specific path. How would i be able to link the file if its in the same folder as the script.

Comment: How are people downloading the program? Is this in an installed Python package (PyPI/Github)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `os` module to get your current filepath.

```
import os
this_dir, this_filename = os.path.split(__file__)
myfile = os.path.join(this_dir, 'configure.txt') 
file = open(myfile)
```

Comment: Relative path is probably the best option here. See here : stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python – Malo 15 secs ago   Edit   Delete

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__file__). Technically not every module has this attribute, but if you're not loading your module from a file, loading a text file from the same folder becomes a moot point anyway.

```
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join

with open(join(dirname(abspath(__file__)), 'configure.txt')):
    ...
```

While this will do what you're asking for, it's not necessarily the best way to store configuration.

Answer (score -1):

```
# import the OS library
import os
# create the absolute location with correct OS path separator to file
config_file = os.getcwd() + os.path.sep + "configure.txt"
# Open file 
file = open(config_file)
```

This method will make sure the correct path separators are used.

Comment: The current working directory need not be the location of the file.

Comment: Relative path is probably the best option here. See here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python