# I can use this program because the file is in my pc. If i want to send this to other pc, it wont work because of the files isnt there

Tags: python

The part of my code is

```
frames = [PhotoImage(file='E:\\omoha\\Documents\\assistant.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(100)]
window.title('Saako')
```

Sorry for messy question. This is my first time ask question!
I want to send this project to my other pc but it wont work because the image is specifically to my directory. How to fix this... Also, it will be nice if there is something like gif url instead of file directory.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this which depend on how you package your program, but for example using `pyinstaller` you can add these types of files as [`datas`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html) that get packaged with your executable.

Comment: Why not transfer the image as well? Also, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a relative path like `assistant.gif` (will search in current working directory) and distribute your program with this gif or download it via internet using `requests` library for example.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working because the directory name changes. You need to have a 'dynamic' directory, and also try sending your project files as a zip.

I modified your code so it can work between computers

```py
import os
global file_path
file_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
frames = [PhotoImage(file=file_path+'\assistant.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(100)]
window.title('Saako')
```

you don't need to install anything with `pip` because os is an included module.