# Finding universal path that will work on both computers while reading the same data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, path, relative-path

How can I change code on both computers into code that will universally recognise the same file (see bellow absolute paths) that is located differently. I don't want to move data and making the same repo locations on both computers because of storage issues on one PC, and I am importing data from my SD card.

PC1:

```
df = pd.read_csv("D:/data/text.txt")
```

PC2:

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Uporabnik/Desktop/desktop/IJS/CESTEL/data/text.txt")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path


if running_on_pc_1():
  base_path = Path("D:")
else:
  base_path = Path("C:/Users/Uporabnik/Desktop/desktop/IJS/CESTEL")

file_path = base_path / "data/text.txt"
```

or...

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

base_path = Path(os.environ.get("BASE_FILE_PATH"))

file_path = base_path / "data/text.txt"
```

or...

```
import json
from pathlib import Path

config = json.loads("config.json")
base_path = Path(config["base_path"])
file_path = base_path / "data/text.txt"
```

and have a config file:

```
{
  "base_path": "C:/Users/Uporabnik/Desktop/desktop/IJS/CESTEL"
}
```

for each PC...:

```
{
  "base_path": "D:"
}
```

Comment: For first example: how can I replace this: running_on_pc_1( ) ?

Comment: For second example: I get an error TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PAthLike object, not NoneType

Comment: For third example: where and how I put two config files ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.path` for this. A quick example if your path id `/data/text.txt`
You just need to specify the relative path from your script.

```py
import os 

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
generic_path= os.path.join(basedir, './data/text.txt')
```

Now the `generic_path` will work on every system !

Comment: __file__ needs to be like this I think '__file__'

Comment: But still I dont get what I want. My output in this case is: 'c:\\Users\\lesko\\OneDrive\\Namizje\\laptop\\IJS\\./data/text.txt' but instead of this I want to get something like this: 'D:\data\text.txt' beacuse this data is on my SD card

Comment: The solution i gave you take the relative path from the python script (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python) that I often use. If the path is too specific you need to hard code them I think like @tom-maclean proposed