# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory But I already have the file and directory

Tags: python, path

I've created this project structure, I've written a py file under lines

```
- Report
  - rep
    - common
    - config
    - Lines
    - static
    - templates
```

as follows

```
import yaml

def read_conf(env='default'):
    data_list = {} # 存储配置
    with open(r"../config/database.yaml", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as ymlfile:
        cfg = yaml.load_all(ymlfile, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
        for data in cfg:
            data_list.update(data)
    if env == 'pro':
        re = data['conf']['pro']
        return re
    re = data['conf'][data[env]]
    return re
if __name__ == '__main__':
    re = read_conf()
    print(re)
```

By running this file directly, I can read the database.yaml file in the config directory, but when I call this function elsewhere, I get an error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../config/database.yaml'
```

I wonder what's the reason for this

expected to happen:
I expect that I can call this function from another file and still get the result

```
{'host': '', 'user': '', 'passwd': '', 'db': '', 'port': }
```

actually resulted:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../config/database.yaml'
```

I use windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want try to change the relative path to absolute path.

```py
import os
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(dirname, 'relative/path/to/file/you/want')
```

[Relative paths in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python)

Comment: I know this way, but I want to know how I wrote the wrong one