# python showing full path

Tags: python

```
import os
def find_method(name):
        i = 0
        found_dic = { "$_GET":[], "$_POST":[], "include":[], "require":[], "mysql_query":[], "SELECT":[], "system":[], "exec":[], "passthru":[], "readfile":[], "fopen":[], "eval":[] }

        for i, line in enumerate(file(name, "r")):
                found = False
                for key in found_dic:
                        if key in line.strip():
                                found_dic[key].append("LINE:"+str(i)+":" + key)
                                found = True

        for key in found_dic:
                if found_dic[key]:
                        print " ", "-"*10, key, "-"*10
                        for r in found_dic[key]:
                               print "  ",r

def search(dirname):
        flist = os.listdir(dirname)
        for f in flist:
                next = os.path.join(dirname, f)
                if os.path.isdir(next):
                        search(next)
                else:
                        doFileWork(next)

def doFileWork(filename):
        ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[-1]
        #if ext == '.html': print filename
        if ext == '.php':
               # print "target:" + filename
                find_method(filename)
```

problem here 
1. I need my result need to show like

```
EX) === /var/www/html/zboard/zboard.php ==
---------- exec ----------
   LINE:288:$a_setup="<a onfocus=blur() href='admin_setup.php?exec=view_board&no=$setup[no]&group_no=$setup[group_no]&exec2=modify' target=_blank>"; else $a_setup="<Zeroboard ";
```

but this only shows like

```
---------- exec ----------
   LINE:287:exec
  ---------- mysql_query ----------
   LINE:43:mysql_query
   LINE:95:mysql_query
   LINE:120:mysql_query
```

how can I show like example using this code

Comment: You really should be using `os.walk` instead of trying to build it yourself on top of `os.listdir` and `os.path.isdir`. (Also, `next` is a built-in function, so you probably don't want to rebind it to mean something else.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking how to get the absolute file path. That question has already been answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python) stackoverflow question.

To repeat the answer you'll find there:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.abspath("mydir/myfile.txt")
```

Comment: I don't think this is his problem. It's not that he's printing a relative path rather than an absolute path, but that he's not printing any path at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have two different problems.

---

First, you apparently want to prefix each batch of "finds" with the file they were found in, like this:

> EX) === /var/www/html/zboard/zboard.php ==

I'm not sure exactly what that format is supposed to be, but… you've got all the info you need in `doFileWork`, and you just aren't printing it. Just add this line to the top of the `doFileWork` function:

```
print "EX) === {} ==".format(filename)
```

If you want to guarantee that it's an absolute path, even if you started with a relative path, just:

```
print "EX) === {} ==".format(os.path.abspath(filename))
```

---

Second, you apparently want each match to print the entire matching line, rather than just the matched key.

Again, you also have the info you need; the problem is that you're explicitly using `key` instead of `line.strip()`. Just replace this:

```
found_dic[key].append("LINE:"+str(i)+":" + key)
```

… with this:

```
found_dic[key].append("LINE:"+str(i)+":" + line.strip())
```