# How to get only files in directory?

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

I have this code:

```
allFiles = os.listdir(myPath)
for module in allFiles:
    if 'Module' in module: #if the word module is in the filename
        dirToScreens = os.path.join(myPath, module)    
        allSreens = os.listdir(dirToScreens)
```

Now, all works well, I just need to change the line

```
allSreens = os.listdir(dirToScreens)
```

to get a list of just files, not folders.
Therefore, when I use

```
allScreens  [ f for f in os.listdir(dirToScreens) if os.isfile(join(dirToScreens, f)) ]
```

it says

```
module object has no attribute isfile
```

NOTE: I am using **Python 2.7**

Comment: There's numerous transcription errors in your examples. Can you please [edit] your question with the *exact same* code as you're using?

Comment: `==` is not an assignment operator, so is the line `allFiles == os.listdir(path)` a typo?

Comment: Nice try, but you still didn't get all of them. Please [edit] again, making sure you are directly copying and pasting from your program.

Comment: @MattDMo hm I can't copy paste, the code is on my PC and for some reason, I cant post on SO using my PC so I have to retype the code in my Mac.

Comment: allScreens = [f for f in allScreens if '.' in f]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use [`os.path.isfile`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path#os.path.isfile) method:

```
import os
from os import path
files = [f for f in os.listdir(dirToScreens) if path.isfile(f)]
```

Or if you feel functional :D

```
files = filter(path.isfile, os.listdir(dirToScreens))
```

Comment: hm, just to confirm, it should be os.listdir('.') and not os.listdir(dirToScreens)? Because before, I was doing "allSreens = os.listdir(dirToScreens)".. I need a list of files in dirToScreens.

Comment: Sorry, replace `"."` to whatever address you need to `listdir`. I just put `"."` to make a point :). I'll fix it.

Comment: yes, they are just typos.

Comment: hm, it is giving me empty lists for some reason when I print files.. any idea why?

Comment: Which one? Both of them?

Comment: hm yea, both. but I'll leave the answer as marked as correct because it might jus be a problem with another part of my code. Your answer seems correct.

Comment: it's weird becuase when I do "allSreens = os.listdir(dirToScreens)" then it gives all folders and files in the directory so it seems as if filtering just the files should work perfectly fine :/

Comment: If you want to make sure the method is correct, try it on an interactive interpreter with just a ramdom dir (like '.'). If it works there, then probably there's something wrong in another part of the code. Are you sure you have any file in your directory? Maybe they are all directories.

Comment: This method only works if `dirToScreens` is the current folder, because `os.listdir` returns only the filenames (not the complete path).

Comment: @hitzg: The purpose was to answer the question, not to make a generic solution. Adapting it should be easy though by using Python's `abspath()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python

Comment: @PauloBu I agree, adapting it is simple. I just felt that stating the limits of the method might be useful for future readers of this post.

Comment: `abspath()` didn't work for me as it is relative to the directory where code is being executed [link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705679/misunderstanding-of-python-os-path-abspath) . Instead I used: 
`files = [f for f in os.listdir(dirToScreens) if path.isfile(path.join(dirToScreens, f))]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3207973/52074

Answer (score 8):

"If you need a list of filenames that all have a certain extension, prefix, or any common string in the middle, use [glob](http://pymotw.com/2/glob/) instead of writing code to scan the directory contents yourself"

```
import os
import glob

[name for name in glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*.*')) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,name))]
```

Comment: for some reason this is returning an empty list for me...

Comment: @juankysmith hm, it is still giving an empty list for me :/

Comment: have you tested it after my modification?

Comment: @juankysmith I did "allScreens = [name for name in glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*.*')) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,name))] print allScreens" and it printed empty lists. I changed it back to "allScreens = os.listdir(dirToScreens) print allScreens" and it printed the list will all files and folders.

Comment: So you are not doing what I recommended to you :) ... glob.glob(os.path.join(path,' * .  * ')) ... Be careful copying and pasting

Comment: @juankysmith also, when you say "glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*.*'))" should I change it to "glob.glob(os.path.join(dirToScreens,'*.*'))"?

Comment: @juankysmith whoops no I did the edit and added the ' * . *' for some reason when I posted on SO it took away the *... also, "os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,name))]" should be "os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirToScreens,name))]" for me, right?