# Misunderstanding of python os.path.abspath

Tags: python, path, os.path

I have following code:

```
directory = r'D:\images'
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    print(os.path.abspath(file))
```

and I want next output:

- D:\images\img1.jpg
- D:\images\img2.jpg and so on

But I get different result:

- D:\code\img1.jpg
- D:\code\img2.jpg

where D:\code is my current working directory and this result is the same as

```
os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file))
```

So, the question is: What is the purpose of os.path.abspath while I must use

```
os.path.normpath(os.path.join(directory, file))
```

to get REAL absolute path of my file? Show real use-cases if possible.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The problem is with your understanding of `os.listdir()` not `os.path.abspath()`. `os.listdir()` returns the names of each of the files in the directory. This will give you:

```
img1.jpg
img2.jpg
...
```

When you pass these to `os.path.abspath()`, they are seen as relative paths. This means it is relative to the directory from where you are executing your code. This is why you get "D:\code\img1.jpg".

Instead, what you want to do is join the file names with the directory path you are listing.

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.join(directory, file))
```

Answer (score 6):

`listdir` produces the file names *in* a directory, with no reference to the name of the directory itself. Without any other information, `abspath` can only form an absolute path from the only directory it can know about: the current working directory. You can always change the working directory before your loop:

```
os.chdir(directory)
for f in os.listdir('.'):
    print(os.path.abspath(f))
```

Answer (score 4):

Python's native `os.listdir` and `os.path` functions are pretty low-level. Iterating through a directory (or a series of descending directories) requires your program to assemble file paths manually. It can be convenient to define a utility function that generates the paths you're going to need just once, so that path assembly logic doesn't have to be repeated in every directory iteration. For example:

```py
import os

def better_listdir(dirpath):
    """
    Generator yielding (filename, filepath) tuples for every
    file in the given directory path.
    """
    # First clean up dirpath to absolutize relative paths and
    # symbolic path names (e.g. `.`, `..`, and `~`)
    dirpath = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(dirpath))

    # List out (filename, filepath) tuples
    for filename in os.listdir(dirpath):
        yield (filename, os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for fname, fpath in better_listdir('~'):
        print fname, '->', fpath
```

Alternatively, there are "higher level" path modules that one can employ, such as [py.path](http://pylib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/path.html), [path.py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/path.py), and [pathlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib) (now a standard part of Python, for version 3.4 and above, but available for 2.7 forward). Those add dependencies to your project, but up-level many aspects of file, filename, and filepath handling.