# Getting the absolute paths of all files in a folder, without traversing the subfolders

Tags: python, absolute-path

Let

```
my_dir = "/raid/user/my_dir"
```

be a folder on my filesystem, which is **not** the current folder (i.e., it's not the result of `os.getcwd()`). I want to retrieve the absolute paths of all files at the first level of hierarchy in `my_dir` (i.e., the absolute paths of all files which are in `my_dir`, but not in a subfolder of `my_dir`) as a list of strings `absolute_paths`. I need it, in order to later delete those files with `os.remove()`.

This is nearly the same use case as

[Get absolute paths of all files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816816/get-absolute-paths-of-all-files-in-a-directory)

but the difference is that I don't want to traverse the folder hierarchy: I only need the files at the first level of hierarchy (at depth 0? not sure about terminology here).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - how to find files and skip directories in os.listdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207936/python-how-to-find-files-and-skip-directories-in-os-listdir)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to adapt that solution: Call `os.walk()` just once, and don't let it continue:

```
root, dirs, files = next(os.walk(my_dir, topdown=True))
files = [ os.path.join(root, f) for f in files ]
print(files)
```

Comment: this works, thanks. Not sure *why* it works, but that's my problem. I'll have a look at the docs.

Comment: To see what's going on, dump `list(os.walk(my_dir, topdown=True))` to your stdout. (I recommend using a small-ish directory tree :-))

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `os.path` module and a list comprehension.

```
import os

absolute_paths= [os.path.abspath(f) for f in os.listdir(my_dir) if os.path.isfile(f)]
```

Comment: nope! It doesn't work **unless** you're running the script from `my_dir`. `os.path.abspath` doesn't really find the absolute path - it only prepends the path of the folder from where you're executing the script (the result of `os.getcwd()`) to the file name. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705679/misunderstanding-of-python-os-path-abspath

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) which returns an [os.DirEntry](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry) object that has a variety of options including the ability to distinguish files from directories.

```
with os.scandir(somePath) as it:
    paths = [entry.path for entry in it if entry.is_file()]
print(paths)
```

If you want to list directories as well, you can, of course, remove the condition from the list comprehension if you want to see them in the list.

The documentation also has this note under `listDir`:

> See also The scandir() function returns directory entries along with file attribute information, giving better performance for many common use cases.

Comment: It's pretty clear in my question that I don't want to list directories, since I say that "I want to retrieve the absolute paths of all files".

Comment: @DeltaIV, I was just trying to be thorough. The above code does exactly that.

Comment: ok, thanks. It looks like your code works too, so I upvoted it.